# How to swap keys for values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Best Way to Exchange Keys with Values in a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/python-best-way-to-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary)

Suppose that I need to swap keys for values in dictionary.

This is what I have in mind (Assuming that the values' value is unique):

```
>>> my_dict = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
>>> my_dict2 = {}
>>> for key, val in my_dict.items():
        my_dict2[val] = key
```

Is there any other efficient way to do it?