# Improvement for swapping keys with values in a dictionay?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've read two questions about exchange keys with values in a dictionary: [Python: Best Way to Exchange Keys with Values in a Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031851/python-best-way-to-exchange-keys-with-values-in-a-dictionary); [How to swap keys for values in a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087694/how-to-swap-keys-for-values-in-a-dictionary).

The best mothod promoted is:

```
dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
```

However, if a dictionary like this:

```
d = {"one":1, "two":2, "a":1}
```

the mothed gets the swapped dictionary:

```
{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
```

The item (1:'a') gets lost. So how can I get a dictionary like this {1: ('one', 'a'), 2: 'two'}? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
In [101]: d = {"one":1, "two":2, "a":1}

In [102]: answer = collections.defaultdict(list)

In [103]: for k,v in d.iteritems():
   .....:     answer[v].append(k)

   .....:     

In [104]: answer
Out[104]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'one'], 2: ['two']})

In [105]: dict(answer)
Out[105]: {1: ['a', 'one'], 2: ['two']}

In [106]: dict((k, tuple(v)) for k,v in answer.iteritems())
Out[106]: {1: ('a', 'one'), 2: ('two',)}
```

If you really want a one-liner (I highly recommend against this - it's very inefficient):

```
In [110]: d
Out[110]: {'a': 1, 'one': 1, 'two': 2}

In [111]: dict((v, tuple([key for key in d if d[key]==v])) for k,v in d.iteritems())
Out[111]: {1: ('a', 'one'), 2: ('two',)}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Many thanks :). Coincidentally, I just got that badge earlier today.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `dict.setdefault()`:

```
In [6]: dd={}

In [7]: for x,y in d.items():
   ...:     dd.setdefault(y,[]).append(x)
   ...:     

In [8]: dd
Out[8]: {1: ['a', 'one'], 2: ['two']}
```

or you can also use `defaultdict()`:

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: d = {"one":1, "two":2, "a":1}

In [3]: dd=defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for x,y in d.items():
   ...:     dd[y].append(x)
   ...:     

In [5]: dd
Out[5]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['a', 'one'], 2: ['two']})
```

Comment: Did we both just post this at the exact same time? (mind=blown)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget NO, you won by 8 seconds. :)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Hey, can you tell me how to use `iPython`? Currently I use IDLE interpreter. I have downloaded the module - iPython, but unable to get how to use it.

Comment: @RohitJain I am on ubuntu, never used it in windows. just do :`sudo apt-get install ipython`, if you're on ubuntu.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. I'm on Windows :-\

Comment: @RohitJain: Get the windows install instructions [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget.. Can you join me on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python

Comment: @RohitJain as Ipython runs in cmd in windows, you might have to download a better terminal application coz copying a text in cmd in pain in the ass.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary.. Yeah you are right. On my laptop, I installed it, and got it work on cmd. Thought there might be some better GUI, that I am unable to get.

Comment: @RohitJain IPython website have suggested this for windows: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: @RohitJain: Another useful Python shell that works well on Windows is [DreamPie](http://www.dreampie.org/).  You might want to check it out.

Comment: @BrenBarn.. Thanks Bren. Will have to wait till I reach home to get that. Download site blocked in office :(

Comment: +1 for `setdefault()` I prefer it to `defaultdict` in most cases, just because it's part of the built-in API

Comment: @acjohnson55 `setdefault()` based solution is also faster than `defaultdict()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {"one":1, "two":2, "a":1}
a = {}
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    a.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

If it has to be a one-liner:

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

a = {k:tuple(b[0] for b in v) for k,v in it.groupby(sorted(d.items(), key=op.itemgetter(1)), key=op.itemgetter(1))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a one liner, but this works:

```
old = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "a": 1}
new = {}

for key, val in old.iteritems():
    new[val] = new.get(val, []) + [key]
```