# Swapping contents of the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which keys and values are to be swapped. For eg:

```
dic = {"indianapolis":"indiana", "columbus":"ohio", "jackson":"mississippi",
  "phoenix":"arizona"}
```

Output should be:

```
{"indiana":"indianapolis", "ohio":"columbus", "mississippi":"jackson",
  "arizona":"phoenix"}
```

Here is what i tried but the constraints are that only `sorted()`, `split()` functions should be used and no other built-in function should be used (like `keys()`, `values()`, `items()`,`lambda`). Not really sure how to proceed further. Can someone help ? I am new to dictionaries.

```
def interchange(input_dict):
    temp = {}
    dic = input_dict
    for i in dict:
        temp[i[1]] = i[0]
    return temp_dic
```

Comment: Another method is shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087694/how-to-swap-keys-for-values-in-a-dictionary

Comment: thank you but i should not use .items() or .iteritems(). That is no inbuilt functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> only `.sorted()`, `.split()` functions should be used

Using `sorted` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> dic = {"indianapolis":"indiana", "columbus":"ohio", "jackson":"mississippi", "phoenix":"arizona"}
>>> {dic[k]:k for k in sorted(dic)}
{'ohio': 'columbus', 'mississippi': 'jackson', 'arizona': 'phoenix', 'indiana': 'indianapolis'}
```

`sorted` returns the keys of dictionary in sorted order, though the order of final dict is going to be arbitrary. The above code is equivalent to:

```
>>> sorted(dic)
['columbus', 'indianapolis', 'jackson', 'phoenix']
>>> new_dic = {}
>>> for k in sorted(dic):
...     new_dic[dic[k]] = k
...     
>>> new_dic
{'ohio': 'columbus', 'mississippi': 'jackson', 'arizona': 'phoenix', 'indiana': 'indianapolis'}
```

**Update:**

```
def interchange(input_dict):
    return {input_dict[k]:k for k in sorted(input_dict)}
... 
>>> interchange(dic)
{'ohio': 'columbus', 'mississippi': 'jackson', 'arizona': 'phoenix', 'indiana': 'indianapolis'}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do i convert it to a "def interchange(input_dict)"function so that i input dic and it gives me a swapped dictionary?

Comment: Do you even need to use `sorted`? wouldn't `{input_dict[k]:k for k in input_dict}` give the same result?

Comment: `sorted()` makes little sense here; the output is a dictionary, after all. The only difference it'll make is if there are duplicate values in the input dictionary; which key ends up in the output is then determined by insertion order. But even that depends on the specific Python implementation; the spec doesn't state what order keys are inserted in a dict comprehension. Practically, it'll be the last inserted key that wins, but that isn't *required* by the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

Using dict comprehension:

```
>>> dic = {"indianapolis":"indiana", "columbus":"ohio",
...        "jackson":"mississippi", "phoenix":"arizona"}
>>> {dic[key]: key for key in dic}
{'ohio': 'columbus', 'mississippi': 'jackson',
 'arizona': 'phoenix', 'indiana': 'indianapolis'}
```

Comment: thank you but i should not use .items() or .iteritems(). That is no inbuilt functions.

Comment: Thanks. But how do i convert it to a "def interchange(input_dict)"function so that i input dic and it gives me a swapped dictionary?

Comment: @Pramod, Just `def interchange(input_dict): return {input_dict[key]: key for key in input_dict}`

Answer (score 0):

**Some nice option:**

```
dic = {"indianapolis":"indiana", "columbus":"ohio", "jackson":"mississippi",
  "phoenix":"arizona"}

newDict = dict(zip(dic.values(),dic.keys()))

print newDict
```

**Output:**

```
{'ohio': 'columbus', 'mississippi': 'jackson', 'arizona': 'phoenix', 'indiana': 'indianapolis'}
```

**Explanation:**

`zip()` returns a list of tuples (dictionery), and the parameters for zip are reversed in order...

**Without python methods:**

```
dic = {"indianapolis":"indiana", "columbus":"ohio", "jackson":"mississippi",
  "phoenix":"arizona"}

newDict = {}

for key, item in dic.iteritems():
    newDict.update({item: key})

print newDict
```

**Output:**

```
{'ohio': 'columbus', 'mississippi': 'jackson', 'arizona': 'phoenix', 'indiana': 'indianapolis'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**very simple**

```
tuple_list = zip(dic.values(),dic.keys())
Result = dict(tuple_list)
```

will produce the required output

```
{'arizona': 'phoenix',
 'indiana': 'indianapolis',
 'mississippi': 'jackson',
 'ohio': 'columbus'}
```

**Edit**
One line solution

```
{ dic[Key]:Key for Key in list(dic) }
```

Comment: OP can't use `.values()` and `.keys()`.

Comment: Those are the constraints OP specified in the question.