# How can you print a key given a value in a dictionary for Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

For example lets say we have the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'A':4,
              'B':6,
              'C':-2,
              'D':-8}
```

How can you print a certain key given its value?

```
print(dictionary.get('A')) #This will print 4
```

How can you do it backwards? i.e. instead of getting a value by referencing the key, getting a key by referencing the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get key by value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do it. It's not how a dictionary is intended to be used...
Instead, you'll have to do something similar to this.

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if 4 == value:
        print key
```

Comment: +1, especially because many keys can contain the searched value

Comment: I think because I'm using python 3 it should be items() instead of iteritems(). Thank you this worked.

Comment: I think you're right about the .items(), I'll edit it into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3:

```
# A simple dictionary
x = {'X':"yes", 'Y':"no", 'Z':"ok"}

# To print a specific key (for instance the 2nd key which is at position 1)
print([key for key in x.keys()][1])
```

Output:

```
Y
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is organized by: key -> value

If you try to go: value -> key

Then you have a few problems; duplicates, and also sometimes a dictionary holds large (or unhashable) objects which you would not want to have as a key.

---

However, if you still want to do this, you can do so easily by iterating over the dicts keys and values and matching them as follows:

```
def method(dict, value):
    for k, v in dict.iteritems():
        if v == value:
            yield k
# this is an iterator, example:
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> for r in method(d, 2):
    print r

b
```

---

As noted in a comment, the whole thing can be written as a generator expression:

```
def method(dict, value):
    return (k for k,v in dict.iteritems() if v == value)
```

---

Python versions note: in Python 3+ you can use `dict.items()` instead of `dict.iteritems()`

Comment: Or, just `return (k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v == value)`

Comment: @nneonneo yes, but I am using a simpler example here.

Comment: Not only large, but also unhashable objects (like most collections) will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
target_key = 4
for i in dictionary:
    if dictionary[i]==target_key:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a dictionary if you have to find the KEY for the highest VALUE please do the following :

1. Step 1: Extract all the VALUES into a list and find the Max of list
2. Step 2: Find the KEY for the particular VALUE from Step 1

The visual analyzer of this code is available in this link : [LINK](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=dictionary%20%3D%20%7B'A'%3A4,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'B'%3A6,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'C'%3A-2,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'D'%3A-8%7D%0Alis%3Ddictionary.values%28%29%0Aprint%28max%28lis%29%29%0Afor%20key,val%20in%20dictionary.items%28%29%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20val%20%3D%3D%20max%28lis%29%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28%22The%20highest%20KEY%20in%20the%20dictionary%20is%20%22,key%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=16&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

```
    dictionary = {'A':4,
              'B':6,
              'C':-2,
              'D':-8}
lis=dictionary.values()
print(max(lis))
for key,val in dictionary.items() :
    if val == max(lis) :
        print("The highest KEY in the dictionary is ",key)
```

Comment: The question is asking to do the reverse lookup in general, not to find the key corresponding to the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is way easier if you use the position of that value within the dictionary.

```
dictionary = {'A':4,
              'B':6,
              'C':-2,
              'D':-8}
 
# list out keys and values separately
key_list = list(dictionary.keys())
val_list = list(dictionary.values())
 
# print key with val 4
position = val_list.index(4)
print(key_list[position])
 
# print key with val 6
position = val_list.index(6)
print(key_list[position])
 
# one-liner
print(list(my_dict.keys())[list(my_dict.values()).index(6)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey i was stuck on a thing with this for ages, all you have to do is swap the key with the value e.g.

```
Dictionary = {'Bob':14}
```

you would change it to

```
Dictionary ={1:'Bob'}
```

or vice versa to set the key as the value and the value as the key so you can get the thing you want