# return dictionaries in list where dictionary key equals value

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a database table with thousands of near duplicates that I would like to merge. I use `psycopg2.extras` to execute a query and eventually get the results in a list of dictionaries.

```
dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
query = """SELECT DISTINCT pat_uid, pat_first_name, pat_last_name, pat_dob_dt, pat_chi_no,
       pat_addr, wtg_uid, wtg_pat_uid, std_uid, std_pat_uid, work_uid, work_pat_uid
       from ((patients left outer join waiting 
       on (pat_uid = wtg_pat_uid)) left outer join studies 
       on (std_pat_uid = pat_uid) left outer join worklist
       on (work_pat_uid = pat_uid)) 
       where (pat_first_name, pat_last_name, pat_chi_no)
       in (SELECT pat_first_name, pat_last_name, pat_chi_no from patients 
       group by pat_first_name, pat_last_name, pat_chi_no
       HAVING count(*) >= 2) AND
       pat_chi_no ~ '^[0-9]{10,10}\$'
       order by pat_last_name asc, pat_first_name asc,
       pat_dob_dt asc"""

# Execute query - find all duplicate patients
dict_cur.execute(query)
# python list containing complete query results
res = dict_cur.fetchall()
```

I then find unique id numbers of each patient using a set

```
 chi_set = set()
 for n in res:
        chi_set.add(n['pat_chi_no'])
```

I then plan to loop through each unique `pat_chi_no` and return the dictionaries which match each `pat_chi_no`. How do I do this efficiently? I have tried the following edited from [How can you print a key given a value in a dictionary for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784590/how-can-you-print-a-key-given-a-value-in-a-dictionary-for-python)

```
def build_dict(seq, key):
    return dict((d[key], dict(d, index=index)) for (index, d) in enumerate(seq))

info_by_chi = build_dict(res, key="pat_chi_no")
info_by_chi["1111111111"]
```

This only returns one dictionary I know there should be 4 entries in this case.

Sample output would be a subset of the complete list of dictionaries i.e. the list would contain only those dictionaries where `lst['pat_chi_no'] == 1111111111`

eg

```
{'index': 4218,
 'pat_addr': '10 DOWNING STREET',
 'pat_chi_no': '1111111111',
 'pat_dob_dt': datetime.date(1937, 9, 24),
 'pat_first_name': 'JOHN',
 'pat_last_name': 'DOE',
 'pat_uid': 35359,
 'std_pat_uid': 35359,
 'std_uid': 37138,
 'work_pat_uid': 35359,
 'work_uid': 366,
 'wtg_pat_uid': 35359,
 'wtg_uid': 11307}


{'index': 122,
     'pat_addr': '10 DOWNING STREET',
     'pat_chi_no': '1111111111',
     'pat_dob_dt': datetime.date(1937, 9, 24),
     'pat_first_name': 'JOHN',
     'pat_last_name': 'DOE',
     'pat_uid': 1233,
     'std_pat_uid': 3455,
     'std_uid': 2323,
     'work_pat_uid': 2455,
     'work_uid': 366,
     'wtg_pat_uid': 3455,
     'wtg_uid': 1127}
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the output of your query, and what you want the final output to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you need to mess about with `dict` or anything like that. If you have a list of dictionaries, you just need to iterate through and find the ones that match. A simple list comprehension will do it:

```
[d for d in res if d['pat_chi_no'] == '1111111111']
```

Comment: Brilliant that does the job. I need to learn list comprehension. Many thanks