# How can I get list of values from dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I get a list of the values in a dict in Python?

In Java, getting the values of a Map as a List is as easy as doing `list = map.values();`.  I'm wondering if there is a similarly simple way in Python to get a list of values from a dict.

Answer (score 997, accepted):

[`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) returns a [*view*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) of the dictionary's values, so you have to wrap it in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

```py
list(d.values())
```

Comment: `iter(d.values())` returns an iterator of the dictionary values in Python 3, which doesn't immediately consume memory.

Comment: @Peterino Yes though in python 3 it would be very rare that you'd need to explicitly invoke `iter(d.values())`. You can just simply iterate the values: `for value in d.values(): ` which by the way, is what everyone would probably be doing in most practical use cases. Usually you don't need a list of dictionary values just for the sake of having a list like in this question. A lot of these Python 2 comments I made are almost useless now and maybe confusing for Python 3 programmers who read this now

Comment: @jamylak: Take this use case: An API wants to return the values of a dictionary. Here you won't iterate (unless you use list or generator comprehensions), you'll apply `list()` or `iter()`, depending on your preference and further processing.

Comment: @Peterino Fair enough

Answer (score 103):

You can use [* operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack dict_values:

```
>>> d = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
>>> [*d.values()]
['a', 'b']
```

or list object

```
>>> d = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
>>> list(d.values())
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: which one is faster?

Comment: @BigChief Some timings were posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736691/1219006 I didn't yet validate them but maybe that helps answer your question. I think what really matters here is clarity over raw speed

Comment: ah very interesting just in general the finding is that unpacking is faster for smaller collections and converting to list for bigger ones

Answer (score 72):

> There should be one ‒ and preferably only one ‒ obvious way to do it.

Therefore `list(dictionary.values())` is the *one way*.

### Yet, considering Python3, what is quicker?

#### `[*L]` vs. `[].extend(L)` vs. `list(L)`

```py
small_ds = {x: str(x+42) for x in range(10)}
small_df = {x: float(x+42) for x in range(10)}

print('Small Dict(str)')
%timeit [*small_ds.values()]
%timeit [].extend(small_ds.values())
%timeit list(small_ds.values())

print('Small Dict(float)')
%timeit [*small_df.values()]
%timeit [].extend(small_df.values())
%timeit list(small_df.values())

big_ds = {x: str(x+42) for x in range(1000000)}
big_df = {x: float(x+42) for x in range(1000000)}

print('Big Dict(str)')
%timeit [*big_ds.values()]
%timeit [].extend(big_ds.values())
%timeit list(big_ds.values())

print('Big Dict(float)')
%timeit [*big_df.values()]
%timeit [].extend(big_df.values())
%timeit list(big_df.values())
```

```sh
Small Dict(str)
256 ns ± 3.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
338 ns ± 0.807 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
336 ns ± 1.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Small Dict(float)
268 ns ± 0.297 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
343 ns ± 15.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
336 ns ± 0.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Big Dict(str)
17.5 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
16.5 ms ± 338 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
16.2 ms ± 19.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Big Dict(float)
13.2 ms ± 41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
13.1 ms ± 919 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
12.8 ms ± 578 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Done on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz.

```sh
# Name                    Version                   Build
ipython                   7.5.0            py37h24bf2e0_0
```

### The result

1. **For small dictionaries `* operator` is quicker**
2. For big dictionaries where it matters `list()` is maybe slightly quicker

Comment: Thanks for sharing the benchmark. So just a small update: On Apple Silicon with Python 3.10 and for big dicts, there is no difference (any more).

Answer (score 20):

Follow the below example --

```
songs = [
{"title": "happy birthday", "playcount": 4},
{"title": "AC/DC", "playcount": 2},
{"title": "Billie Jean", "playcount": 6},
{"title": "Human Touch", "playcount": 3}
]

print("====================")
print(f'Songs --> {songs} \n')
title = list(map(lambda x : x['title'], songs))
print(f'Print Title --> {title}')

playcount = list(map(lambda x : x['playcount'], songs))
print(f'Print Playcount --> {playcount}')
print (f'Print Sorted playcount --> {sorted(playcount)}')

# Aliter -
print(sorted(list(map(lambda x: x['playcount'],songs))))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to assign the values as a list to a variable, another method using the unpacking `*` operator is

```py
*values, = d.values()
```

###### Get a list of values of specific keys in a dictionary

Most straightforward way is to use a comprehension by iterating over `list_of_keys`. If `list_of_keys` includes keys that are not keys of `d`, `.get()` method may be used to return a default value (`None` by default but can be changed).

```py
res = [d[k] for k in list_of_keys] 
# or
res = [d.get(k) for k in list_of_keys]
```

As often the case, there's a method built into Python that can get the values under keys: `itemgetter()` from the built-in `operator` module.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
res = list(itemgetter(*list_of_keys)(d))
```

Demonstration:

```py
d = {'a':2, 'b':4, 'c':7}
list_of_keys = ['a','c']
print([d.get(k) for k in list_of_keys])
print(list(itemgetter(*list_of_keys)(d)))
# [2, 7]
# [2, 7]
```

###### Get values of the same key from a list of dictionaries

Again, a comprehension works here (iterating over list of dictionaries). As does mapping `itemgetter()` over the list to get the values of specific key(s).

```py
list_of_dicts = [ {"title": "A", "body": "AA"}, {"title": "B", "body": "BB"} ]

list_comp = [d['title'] for d in list_of_dicts]
itmgetter = list(map(itemgetter('title'), list_of_dicts))
print(list_comp)
print(itmgetter)
# ['A', 'B']
# ['A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want return a `list` by default (as in python 2) instead of a `view`, one can create a new dict class and overwrite the `values` method:

```py
class ldict(dict):
    # return a simple list instead of dict_values object
    values = lambda _: [*super().values()]

d = ldict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
d.values()   # [1, 2]   (instead of dict_values([1, 2]))
```

Answer (score -4):

```
out: dict_values([{1:a, 2:b}])

in:  str(dict.values())[14:-3]    
out: 1:a, 2:b
```

Purely for visual purposes. Does not produce a useful product... Only useful if you want a long dictionary to print in a paragraph type form.