# Convert a list of dictionaries to an unordered list of just values?

Tags: python

How can I quickly convert a list of dictionaries to a simple list of just the values if the order is not important?

For example:

```
results = [{'id':'abcd'},
           {'id':'bcde'},
           {'id':'cdef'}]
```

to simply

```
results = ('abcd','bcde','cdef')
```

Comment: Probably need to reword your question. That's not a dictionary of key-value pairs. Its a list of dictionaries.

Comment: [Possible dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16228248/1982962)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
>>> results = [{'id':'abcd'},
...            {'id':'bcde'},
...            {'id':'cdef'}]
>>>
>>> tuple(d['id'] for d in results)
('abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef')
```

Note that this is not a *list* but rather a *tuple*. If you want a list instead:

```
>>> [d['id'] for d in results]
['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
>>> [val for dic in results for val in dic.values()]

['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']
```

If you want a tuple, just enclose in `tuple` with parens instead:

```
>>> tuple(val for dic in results for val in dic.values())

('abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef')
```

Both of the above work even if dictionaries have more than one value, and regardless of what the keys in the dictionaries are.

Comment: Is the list created by `dic.values()` needed?

Comment: Idea is to make things work regardless of keys. It's all in a list comprehension, so Python interpreter can figure out the fastest way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This will fit your sample data:

```
import operator
map(operator.itemgetter('id'), results)
```

e.g.

```
results = [{'id':'abcd'},
       {'id':'bcde'},
       {'id':'cdef'}]

import operator
print map(operator.itemgetter('id'), results)

>>> ['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']
```

BUT, in a general way, you can chain the values of each dictionary in list:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.chain(*map(dict.values, results)))

>>> ['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you essentially want to do is concatenate the values of all the dictionaries into one list. The built-in`reduce()`function makes translating that into code relatively easy:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, (d.values() for d in results))
```

will give:

```
['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef']
```

You can add an outer  call to`tuple()`, if that's what you really want to get:

```
('abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef')
```