# How do you convert a Dictionary to a List?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

For example, if the Dictionary is `{0:0, 1:0, 2:0}` making a list: `[0, 0, 0]`.

If this isn't possible, how do you take the minimum of a dictionary, meaning the dictionary: `{0:3, 1:2, 2:1}` returning `1`?

Comment: `dict.values()` will give you the values as a list (more or less)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: simplest way to get list of values from dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/python-simplest-way-to-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

convert a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to a list is pretty simple, you have 3 flavors for that [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), [`.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

```
>>> test = {1:30,2:20,3:10}
>>> test.keys() # you get the same result with list(test)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> test.values()
[30, 20, 10]
>>> test.items()
[(1, 30), (2, 20), (3, 10)]
>>>
```

(in python 3 you would need to call list on those)

finding the maximum or minimum is also easy with the [min](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min) or [max](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#max) function

```
>>> min(test.keys()) # is the same as min(test)
1
>>> min(test.values())
10
>>> min(test.items())
(1, 30)
>>> max(test.keys()) # is the same as max(test)
3
>>> max(test.values())
30
>>> max(test.items())
(3, 10)
>>>
```

(in python 2, to be efficient, use the [.iter*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) versions of those instead )

the most interesting one is finding the key of min/max value, and min/max got that cover too

```
>>> max(test.items(),key=lambda x: x[-1])
(1, 30)
>>> min(test.items(),key=lambda x: x[-1])
(3, 10)
>>>
```

here you need a key function, which is a function that take one of whatever you give to the main function and return the element(s) (you can also transform it to something else too) for which you wish to compare them.

[lambda](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#lambda) is a way to [define](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) [anonymous](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=lambda#function) functions, which save you the need of doing this

```
>>> def last(x):
        return x[-1] 

>>> min(test.items(),key=last)
(3, 10)
>>>
```

Comment: .items() is genius. I didn't know such a thing existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply take the **minimum** with:

```
min(dic.values())
```

And **convert it to a list** with:

```
list(dic.values())
```

but since a **dictionary is unordered**, the order of elements of the resulting list is undefined.

In [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) you do not need to call `list(..)` simply `dic.values()` will be sufficient:

```
dic.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = {0:0, 1:2, 2:4}
>>> a.keys()
[0, 1, 2]
>>> a.values()
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: yeah, saw that a second later :p

Comment: you are *quick*! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is my one-liner solution for a flattened list of keys and values:

```
d = {'foo': 'bar', 'zoo': 'bee'}
list(sum(d.items(), tuple()))
```

And the result:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'zoo', 'bee']
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is defined as the following:

```
dict{[Any]:[Any]} = {[Key]:[Value]}
```

The problem with your question is that you haven't clarified what the keys are.

1: Assuming the keys are just numbers and in *ascending order without gaps*, `dict.values()` will suffice, as other authors have already pointed out.

2: Assuming the keys are just numbers in strictly ascending order but not in the right order:

```
i = 0
list = []
while i < max(mydict.keys()):
     list.append(mydict[i])
     i += 1
```

3: Assuming the keys are just numbers but not in strictly ascending order:
    There still is a way, but you have to get the keys first and do it via the maximum of the keys and an `try-except` block

4: If none of these is the case, maybe `dict` is not what you are looking for and a 2d or 3d array would suffice? **This also counts if one of the solutions do work. `Dict` seems to be a bad choice for what you are doing**.

Comment: `i++` is not valid python

Comment: also, there is no need to assume anything about the keys (or values) other than they can be compared with one another to find min/max, you go to some weird tangent there

Comment: in your example 2, you assume that that the keys are numbers for, actually I don't understand your goal there :-/ In your point 1, why you would assume that? likewise in point 3, and what is the point of point 4?

Comment: The point of point 4? I wasn't sure what he wanted, but if the keys are numbers, one could simply use an array with the index correlating to the key. {0:1, 3:2, 2:3} would mean that the list looks like [1, 3, 2].

Comment: I wasn't quite sure what the questioner wanted, that's why I provided them with 4 options