# .index() generates AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python

I'm trying to rewrite this Python2 code to Python3 accepted syntax. The .index() methods generates the following error:

AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'

This is because .index() is no valid syntax in Python3. I've read that a list should be used to work around the problem, but I can't figure out how to do it. Anyone any idea how to work around the problem?

```
words1 = [self._word_to_id.keys()[self._word_to_id.values().index(data_x[index])] for index in range(len(puncts) - 1)]
indices = [i for i, w in enumerate(words1) if w in PUNCTUATIONS]
for i in indices:
    words1[i], words1[i-1] = words1[i-1], words1[i] 
words2 = [self._word_to_id.keys([self._word_to_id.values().index(data_x[index])] for index in range(len(puncts) - 1, len(data_x))]
all_words = words1 + [puncts[-1]] + words2  
content = ' '.join(all_words)  
min_step = len(puncts)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you be able to provide some *reproducible* (including desired output) code so we can test solutions? Please also read *[mcve]*.

Comment: `self._word_to_id.values().index(....` -> `list(self._word_to_id.values()).index(....` to get rid of this error. But using `enumerate` here, would make the code much more readable. Also, are you sure it's `range(len(puncts) - 1` (**-1**)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/python-simplest-way-to-get-list-of-values-from-dict#16228268

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work: `'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`

Answer (score 8):

You are calling `self._word_to_id.values()` which returns the class `dict_values` and not `list`. `dict_values` does not inherit from `list` and does not have the `index` method because of that.

You need to convert your dictionary values into a `list` to use the `index` function. Try this:

```
list(self._word_to_id.values()).index(data_x[index])
```

Comment: The next error occurs upon working with you suggestion: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing.

Code:
`[self._word_to_id.keys()[list(self._word_to_id.values()).index(data_x[index])] for index in range(len(puncts) - 1, len(data_x))]`

Comment: @WolfgangPlato , the `self._word_to_id.keys()` is also a dict_keys object. You need to convert it to a list by `list(self._word_to_id.keys())` and then you can index it. I have had this problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

`words1 = [list(self._word_to_id.keys())[list(self._word_to_id.values()).index(data_x[index])] for index in range(len(puncts) - 1)]`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.