# zip for dict of list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried `zip` with a list of list and it worked.

```
data_list = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [1, 3, 7],
   [5, 8, 1]
]
total = [sum(x) for x in zip(*data_list)]
```

`total` was as expected:

```
[7, 13, 11]
```

now I have dictionary

```
data_dict = {
   'a': [1, 2, 3],
   'b': [1, 3, 7],
   'c': [5, 8, 1]
}
```

and I want exact same output as mentioned above. How can I do that with `data_dict`?

Comment: Your `data_dict` is not a valid python dictionary, but if it were you might be looking for `total = [sum(x) for x in zip(*data_dict.values())]`. **Edit**: It wasn't valid before the edit by @meowgoesthedog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Comment: I was trying with map(dict.items, data_dict) inside zip() but it solved my problem. Thanks a lot @pault :D

Comment: Be aware of issues related to order. See related: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744)

Comment: I already have an ordered dict(used collections.OrderedDict) and all the lists in this dictionary has the same len(). Thanks again for mentioning the corner case.

Answer (score 2):

```
total = [sum(x) for x in zip(*data_dict.values())]
```

`values()` returns the values of the items in the dict. This gives you an Iterable of lists, which is pretty close to the first example.

Comment: *Assuming* you have an ordered dict and the lists were added in the same order.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem relevant for this use case.

Comment: How is it relevant? The result is the same.

Comment: I understand he wants list `[7, 13, 11]`. OP can clarify if I misunderstood and my answer is inaccurate.