# Read multiple CSVs & merge those CSVs into separate files based on year in filename python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Suppose I have the following data sets that I successfully read into my notebook:

```
data1-format1-1991-1992.csv
data2-format1-1993-1994.csv
data3-format1-1995-1996.csv

data4-format2-1991-1992.csv
data5-format2-1993-1994.csv
data6-format2-1995-1996.csv
```

I can easily read these sets in, from their own directories like so:

```
files1 = [filename for filename in os.listdir(master_dir_1) if filename.startswith("data-")] # would do same for second set of files, in master_dir_2

for filename in files1:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    print(df)
```

This prints them out in one frame - but I need to read them in, and then `pd.merge()` each separate file based on the year in the file name. E.g., `data1-format1-1991-1992.csv` gets joined with `data1-format2-1991-1992.csv`, and so on.

The process would be to read in both sets from their own directories with the loop above, and then have another loop that combines and saves based on the matching years in the file names (I think). How do I split based on the years, and save each joined file separately, with the years in the saved csv name? I've got the process for reading in single data sets and joining/saving, but not for multiple read ins, joins, and saves.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033461/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-pandas-dataframes) gets me some of the way there, because of how `.format()` is utilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a for loop with a `.groupby`

```
for year, x in df.groupby(['Year']):
    x.to_csv(f'data1-format1-{year}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: read everything into one dataframe first and then you can do something like this to spit it all back out into multiple files.

Comment: @papelr did this answer your question? If so, please accept!

Answer (score 1):

```
years = [name.split('-')[-2:] for name in names]
years = ['-'.join(y) for y in years]
years = set(years) #unique years
print(years)

dataformat = [name.split('-')[:2] for name in names]
dataformat = ['-'.join(df) for df in dataformat]
print(dataformat)

year_data = dict()
for year in years:
    yragne=year.split('.')[0] 
    year_data[yragne] = pd.DataFrame([])
    for df in dataformat:
        try:
            gg = pd.read_csv(rootdir+'/'+df+'-'+year,header = None)
            print(gg)
            year_data[yragne] = year_data[yragne].append(pd.read_csv(rootdir+'/'+df+'-'+year,header = None),True)
        except:
            pass
```