# list comprehension with python dictionaries in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have recently started using python 3 and while working on list comprehension I am seeing something completely different from python 2. I want to know why is it that while printingthe value of 'y' python3 is returning [dict_values([1]), dict_values([2])] instead of [1,2] and how I can get response in desired form i.e,[1,2]

```
>>> x=[{'x':1},{'y':2}]
>>> y=[i.values() for i in x]
>>> y
[dict_values([1]), dict_values([2])]
```

Comment: Perhaps more directly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict

Comment: answer to my question is not available in the above link, I am not sure why you closed this issue.

Comment: Yes it is. Please read the first question/answer linked

Comment: The answer is >>>y=[i[j] for i in x for j in i]