# Ordering a dictionary with multiple values ​in one key

Tags: python, dictionary

The dictionary contains the following values ​​with names and age of different people. I must order this dictionary from least to greatest in a list. That is, the index `0` must occupy it `('JOHN', 1)` and the `-1` must occupy it `('RYAN', 25)`.

```
dictionary = {1: ('RYAN', 25), 2: ('WILL', 12), 3: ('JOHN', 1), 4: ('MATT', 15),
              5: ('FILL', 19), 6: ('NICK', 4)}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) and [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples by the element at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples-by-the-element-at-a-given-index)

Comment: I might have misunderstood the "dictionary sorting" part. See this instead: [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 2):

Talking about an `index` of a dictionary doesn't make much sense. If you want an index, you should make a list. You can make a list of `values()` and sort that with a key. For example:

```
d = {1:('RYAN',25),2:('WILL',12),3:('JOHN',1),4:('MATT',15),5:('FILL',19),6:('NICK',4)}

list(sorted(d.values(), key = lambda x: x[1]))
```

Result:

```
[('JOHN', 1),
 ('NICK', 4),
 ('WILL', 12),
 ('MATT', 15),
 ('FILL', 19),
 ('RYAN', 25)]
```

If you really need a dict, you can pass this list back to `OrderedDict()` (or `dict()` in newer versions of python that preserve order), but you won't be able to index it with zero or -1 unless you pull out the values or keys and convert those to a list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {1:('RYAN',25),2:('WILL',12),3:('JOHN',1),4:('MATT',15),5:('FILL',19),6:('NICK',4)}

od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.values(), key = lambda x: x[1]))

od.keys()
# odict_keys(['JOHN', 'NICK', 'WILL', 'MATT', 'FILL', 'RYAN'])
```