# rpy2 conversion-> passing a python dict to a ... argument in R

Tags: python, r

I have a python dictionary with values defined as follows:

```
dc = {
    '1': 100,
    '2': 150,
    '3': 200
  }
```

And a r function defined as follows:

```
Printer <- function(...) {
    for (i in list(...)) {
        print (i)
    }
}
```

So the output would be

```
 100
 150
 200
```

The error I get when trying to pass the argument through rpy2 is

> RuntimeError: Unknown data type <class 'dict'> to pass to R algorithm.

Question: How do I convert the elements of the python dictionary to an r list during passing from python to R?

Comment: Alternately Can I pass a dict argument to R and perhaps convert it to a list in the R function (just thinking out aloud of my options here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple use case and a flat dict this snippet can be utilized.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
a = robjects.r('list(foo="barbat", fizz=123)')
```

Here is a snippet for conversion:

```
def _dict_to_rlist(dd):
    pairs = []
    for k,v in dd.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            pairs.append("{}=\"{}\"".format(k, v))
        else:
            pairs.append("{}={}".format(k, v))
    cmd = "list({})".format(",".join(pairs))
    lst = ro.r(cmd)
    return lst
```