# Python & JSON | Can't access dictionary using an index

Tags: python, json, dictionary, wikipedia-api

I have a program that looks like this:

```py
import json
import requests
article_name = "BT Centre"
article_api_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles={}".format(article_name)
called_data = requests.get(article_api_url)
formatted_data = called_data.json()
print(formatted_data)
pages = formatted_data["query"]["pages"]
print(pages)
first_page = pages[0]["extract"]
print(first_page)
```

For the first print statement, where it prints the whole JSON, it returns this:

```json
{
  'batchcomplete': '',
  'query':{
    'pages':{
      '18107207':{
        'pageid': 18107207,
        'ns': 0,
        'title':'BT Centre',
        'extract': "The BT Centre is the global headquarters and registered office of BT Group..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to access the "extract" data with the `first_page` variable, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wiki_json_printer.py", line 15, in <module>
    first_page = pages[0]["extract"]
KeyError: 0
```

The problem is, I can't set `first_page` to `pages["18107207"]["extract"]` because the Page ID changes for every article.

---

Edit: Solution from **Ann Zen** works:

> You can use a for loop to loop through the keys of the pages
> dictionary, and detect which one is the ID via the str.isdigit()
> method:
>
> ```py
> for key in pages:
>     if key.isdigit():
>         print(pages[key]["extract"])
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Comment: Try `pages.values()[0]["extract"]`. See the suggested duplicate question for more explanation.

Comment: Thank you, fortunately, a solution has already been provided, but I will try yours too. Edit: Tested it out, doesn't seem to work, sorry.

Comment: @HåkenLid The post you linked is not a duplicate of this post. This post wants to get the key that is the ID, with the ID varying each time, while the post you linked only aims to get a list of all the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to loop through the keys of the `pages` dictionary, and detect which one is the ID via the [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method:

```
for key in pages:
    if key.isdigit():
        print(pages[key]["extract"])
```

Comment: if OP knows there is only ever 1 key `pages[pages.keys()[0]]` and it's just some page id that changes, no loops required

Comment: @depperm The OP must've reduced the dictionary to provide a minimal code :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `next` on an iterator on the dict to find the first key:

```
...
key = next(iter(pages))
first_page = pages[key]["extract"]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`pages` is dictionary not a `list` you can't select it by index, use it key

```
print(pages['18107207']['extract'])
```

of course the following will work because the `key` is `18107207`

```
for key in pages:
    print(pages[key]["extract"])
```