# want to get only mobile number and take them into other variable

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm making a telegram bot and using update and context from `telegram.ext` module in Python.
look at this code:

```
{ctelegram.messageentity.MessageEntity object at exe88882A8D1B3CD38>: +919116348047"}
```

This is output of my variable I want to take only phone number from it is there any way to get only phone numbers?

I'll show you some part of my code I had used to print this?

```py
def search(update, context):
    number = update.message.parse_entities(types=MessageEntity.PHONE NUMBER)
    context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,text=("working on it..."))
    print(number)
```

Comment: Try `.values()`.

Comment: I had tried this but still get this... Dict_value(['+9196636373'])  I only want no to be printed

Comment: something like this `*list(object_name.values())` will work I guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)