# Create dictionaries from data frames stored in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a for loop that cycles through and creates 3 data frames and stores them in a dictionary. From each of these data frames, I would like to be able to create another dictionary, but I cant figure out how to do this.

Here is the repetitive code without the loop:

```
Trad = allreports2[allreports2['Trad'].notna()]  
Alti = allreports2[allreports2['Alti'].notna()]  
Alto = allreports2[allreports2['Alto'].notna()]  

Trad_dict = dict(zip(Trad.State, Trad.Position))  
Alti_dict = dict(zip(Alti.State, Alti.Position))  
Alto_dict = dict(zip(Alto.State, Alto.Position))
```

As stated earlier, I understand how to make the 3 dataframes by storing them in a dictionary and I understand what needs to go on the right side of the equal sign in the second statement in the for loop, but not what goes on the left side (denoted below as XXXXXXXXX).

```
Routes = ['Trad', 'Alti', 'Alto']  
dfd = {}  
for route in Routes:  
    dfd[route] = allreports2[allreports2[route].notna()]  
    XXXXXXXXX = dict(zip(dfd[route].State, dfd[route].Position))
```

(Please note: I am very new to Python and teaching myself so apologies in advance!)

Comment: Are you using pandas? If so, you can use `df.to_dict()`

Comment: Why don't you just put them in the dict???

Comment: @juanpa Canonical question for that: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341)

Comment: So, it's really not clear the output you require.

Comment: @DeMO yes, I am using pandas, but how would I use df.to_dict()? Ultimately I want the 3 dictionaries that have the same name as what I would wind up with using the repetitive code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compromises readability, but this should work.

```py
Routes = ['Trad', 'Alti', 'Alto']
dfd, output = [{},{}] # Unpack List
for route in Routes:
 dfd[route] = allreports2[allreprots2[route].notna()]
 output[route] = dict(zip(dfd[route].State, dfd[route].Position))
Trad_dict, Alti_dict, Alto_dict = list(output.values()) # Unpack List
```

Reference

[How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Comment: Thank you so much. This did exactly what I needed. I really appreciate it!!!