# How to extract keys from the json db with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

So i got custom database in python that looks like this

```
{"1":"0xAD488499b897a9667395526C39d0f3314A0f3FE9","2":"0xAD48843b897449667395526C39d0f3314A0f3FE9"}
```

And I want to extract only addresses I got other database that keeps count of how many addresses they are

```
db = DB("db/addrtouser.db")
db1 = DB("db/addrstorage.db")
db2 = DB("db/number.db")

    how = db2.get("how") # how many addreses they are

    checkaddr = #only second addreses
    for element in checkaddr:
        print('check')
        json = await tools.getonl(element)
        if json == False:
            author = int(db.get(element))
            owner = await client.fetch_user(author)  # your user ID
            await owner.send("YOUR NODE IS NOT ONLINE!")
```

I want checkaddr to be `"0xAD488499b897a9667395526C39d0f3314A0f3FE9","0xAD48843b897449667395526C39d0f3314A0f3FE9"`
So to just extract 2nds from the database with some while or for loop

Comment: What varibable type is `how`? If it is a simple dictionary you can use `how.values()` to access its values

Comment: @CarlesMitjans its a int {"how": 2}

Comment: I think what we need is the type of db, db1, db2.  Hopefully they are dictionaries.  If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict (shows how for Python versions 2 and 3)

Comment: Also, your title says you want to extract keys, but in your question it appears that you want to extract a list of the values, without the keys.  Which one are you trying to do?

Comment: @Basya so i want to from ```{1:a,2:b}`` to get '''[a,b]```

Comment: Well, that looks like going from a dict to a list; take a look at the question I linked to -- that may have the answer you need, ready-made.

Comment: Oh, and (I should have started with this!) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Basya im getting error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9QBexE7z

Comment: I'm sorry you are getting an error and would be happy to help you try to solve it, but I'll need a bit more detailed information.  What have you tried?  What error are you getting?  What are the types of your variables?

Comment: OK, you are trying to get the values from checkaddr, but checkaddr is not a dict.  I thought you wanted to get the values from your database?

Comment: @Basya so i have func that reads from json db,    ``` checkaddr = db1.dumpdb()#  second addreses```
but its saying that data dump is bool

Comment: ```  File "main.py", line 22, in test1
    checkaddr1 = list(checkaddr.values())
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'values'``

Comment: Well then I guess you'll have to find out more about the database types and functions you are using.  I don't know what they are, or from what library (if any) they come.

Comment: I use this custom database https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-a-simple-toy-database-in-python-within-minutes-51ff49f47f1/

Comment: Well, if so, it is clear why is saying that the return of dumpdb is bool:   def dumpdb(self):
        try:
            json.dump(self.db , open(self.location, "w+"))
            return True
        except:
            return False

Comment: For us to help you you first need to do some homework.  Figure out what the types are of your variables, and which exact one has the information you want to work with.  Then we can help you figure out how to do it.  We can not figure out for you what you already have.  If you can provide us with a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we will be best able to help you.

Comment: @Basya fixed just add get all and its fixed

Comment: Sorry for my bad english sorry

Comment: Glad you worked it out; I am still not clear on what you had and what you did but I don't need it anymore...  And, bad English is no crime; I think I understood your English OK.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values from a dictionary, do this:

```
my_dict = {"first_key": 1, "second_key": 2}
print(list(my_dict.values()))
```

This will print:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: This duplicates the answers to the question linked to in the comments on the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict.