# How to print all key's value except the key in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict:

````
A = {'serial1': 'x1', 'serial2': 'x2', 'serial3': 'x3', 'serial4': 'x5', 'serial5': 'x5'}```
````

How can I get only the value of each keys? I only want to retrieve the value and remove the key.

Expected Output:

```
A = {'x1',  'x2',  'x3', 'x5', 'x5'}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Comment: `A.values()`  ??

Comment: The expected output should be `A = ['x1',  'x2',  'x3', 'x5', 'x5']` (note the square brackets `[]`), because dictionaries _must_ have keys. What you want is a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B = A.values()
print(B)

>>> ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x5', 'x5']
```

```
B = [item[1] for item in A.items()]
print(B)

>>> ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x5', 'x5']
```