# dict.values() doesn't return a list as expected

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get values from my dictionary here

```
for elem in set(sample_txt):

       d = {elem:sample_txt.count(elem)}

print(d.values())
```

d.values() should return a list of values:

> The methods dict. keys() and dict. values() return lists of the keys
> or values explicitly. There's also an items() which returns a list of
> (key, value) tuples, which is the most efficient way to examine all
> the key value data in the dictionary.
> ***from developers.google.com***

So I should get something like `['a', 'b', 'etc']`. However in my example I get:

`type(d.values())` ---> <class 'dict_values'>

What's wrong?

Comment: You're replacing `d` every time through the loop, not adding to it. So you'll only get the last value from the loop. Use `d[elem] = sample_txt.count(elem)`

Comment: Ty @Barmar, that is also a mistake here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quote you posted is related to python2, where indeed it returned `list`. In python3 you need to cast it by yourself `list(d.values())`

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
Python 3.10.2 (main, Feb  2 2022, 06:19:27) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
```

For Python 3, `d.values()` returns a [dict_value object](https://peps.python.org/pep-3106/) which is one of the [dict view classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views):

```
>>> txt='abcaaab'
>>> d={k:txt.count(k) for k in set(txt)}
>>> d
{'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d.values()
dict_values([4, 1, 2])
```

One of the neat things about dict views is the view is updated if the underlying dict changes:

```
>>> d
{'a': 4, 'c': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> v=d.values()
>>> v
dict_values([4, 1, 2])
>>> d['z']='live update!'
>>> v
dict_values([4, 1, 2, 'live update!'])
```

---

Depending on the version of Python, the representation *may* include the contents or *may* include only the class.