# Dict multiple value to a list in python

Tags: python

How to convert my dict value in a list?

Input

```
My_dict={{'x':112,'y':987,'z':56},{'x':12,'y':97,'z':516},{'x':1912,'y':7,'z':26},...}
```

Output

```
My_list=[[112,987,56],[12,97,516],[1912,7,26],...]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict) ... do this in a loop or list comprehension.

Comment: `My_dict` is not a valid data structure. It seems that it is a dict of dict, but the first layer has no key, only values. Did you mean `My_dict=[{'x':112,'y':987,'z':56},{'x':12,'y':97,'z':516},{'x':1912,'y':7,'z':26}]` ?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: It's working using that link 'How can I get lost of values from dict?'

Comment: My_dict={'1': {'x':112,'y':987,'z':56}, '2': {'x':12,'y':97,'z':516}, '3': {'x':1912,'y':7,'z':26}}
print(My_dict)
My_list = []
for key, value in My_dict.items():
    tmpList = []
    for key2, value2 in value.items():
        tmpList.append(value2)
    My_list.append(tmpList)
print(My_list)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you meant

```
my_list_of_dicts =[{'x':112,'y':987,'z':56},
         {'x':12,'y':97,'z':516},
         {'x':1912,'y':7,'z':26}]
```

Because the data structure is not correct for your `My_dict`.

If so, you can use list comprehension as below

```
[list(inner_dict.values()) for inner_dict in my_list_of_dicts]
```