# How do I print a single symbol with python fetch_balance() CCXT?

Tags: python, binance, cryptocurrency, ccxt

I am able to pull a balance of all symbols but how do I print just a single symbol balance? Here is the code I already have working just not sure how to get say USDT to print a balance.

```
import ccxt
import config

binanceus = ccxt.binanceus({
'apiKey': config.API_KEY,
'secret': config.API_SECRET

})

def trade_crypto(request):
    balance = binanceus.fetch_balance()
    
    print(balance)

    return {
        "balance": list(balance.keys())
    }
```

I am trying to print USDT just not sure of the syntax needed. Thanks!

Comment: this return a `dict`,  you you just need to access the correct key from the dict. Post the example dict that you have and any user can tell you how to do this....

Comment: I am such a newb. What is dict? If you mean dictionary then it should be the CCXT library?

Comment: no, the CCTX is broadly implemented well (i have posted an answer which works for me). You need to get a grasp of basic python (which is the part letting you down). I posted and example too and also a good started book (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BHL2XKCR) that will help you.

Comment: You are so awesome thank you so much for your help. I am going to get this book right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the code in the question works or at least i could get it to work with the `binance` website. (i dont have `binanceus` but the cctx library seems to offer more than just one vendor).

Also, note that you don't need curly braces on the return statement in python.

So i did this to verify:

```py
import ccxt

import sys
sys.path.append('G:\\path\\to\\creds\\python\\binance')
import creds

binance = ccxt.binance({
'apiKey': creds.API_Key,
'secret': creds.Secret_Key

})

def trade_crypto():
    balance = binance.fetch_balance()
    
    # print(balance)

    return balance

x = trade_crypto()
print(x)
```

The above returns a python dictionary.

From this, you can get the values that you seek.

It looks like you used this stack question for the answer:
[How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

But the dictionary has nested dictionaries and lists, so you need to understand the structure to achieve what you want.

Whilst i dont know the exact structure, the answer will generically look like this:

```py
nested_dict = {
    'key1': {
        'key2': 'value'
    }
}

# Get the value from the nested dictionary
value = nested_dict['key1']['key2']
print(value)  # Output: "value"
```

You need to post the dict for someone to clearly help if you are stuck there...

here is a useful python book for a newb:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BHL2XKCR

Comment: Bingo- this is it. The nested values did the trick.