# Dynamic values within a JSON parameter using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

To be clear, I am practicing my Python skills using CoinMarketCaps API.

The below code works great:

```
import json

# 1 JSON string in list, works
info_1_response = ['{"status": {"timestamp": "2023-01-25T22:59:58.760Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 16, "credit_count": 1, "notice": null}, "data": {"BTC": {"id": 1, "name": "Bitcoin", "symbol": "BTC"}}}']

for response in info_1_response:
    info_1_dict = json.loads(response)
    #print(info_1_dict) #works
    data = info_1_dict['data']['BTC']
    print(f"only id = {data['id']}")
```

**OUTPUT**: only id = 1

However, if I have 2 responses in a list, how would I got about getting the ID for each symbol (BTC/ETH)? Code:

```
info_2_response = ['{"status": {"timestamp": "2023-01-25T22:59:58.760Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 16, "credit_count": 1, "notice": null}, "data": {"BTC": {"id": 1, "name": "Bitcoin", "symbol": "BTC"}}}', '{"status": {"timestamp": "2023-01-25T22:59:59.087Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 16, "credit_count": 1, "notice": null}, "data": {"ETH": {"id": 1027, "name": "Ethereum", "symbol": "ETH"}}}']
for response in info_2_response:
    info_2_dict = json.loads(response)
    #print(info_2_dict) #works
    print(info_2_dict['data']) #works
```

**OUTPUT:**

`{'BTC': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'symbol': 'BTC'}}`

`{'ETH': {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ETH'}}`

But what if I ***only*** wanted the ID? It seems as if I would need a dynamic parameter as so:

`data = info_2_dict['data']['DYNAMIC PARAMETER-(BTC/ETH)']`

`print(f"only id = {data['id']}")`

**Desired Output:** 1, 1027

is this possible?

Comment: just nest another loop: `for coin, coin_data in info_1_dict['data'].items(): print(coin, coin_data['id'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get list of values from dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228248/how-can-i-get-list-of-values-from-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate another level:

```
>>> for response in info_2_response:
...     response = json.loads(response)
...     for coin, data in response['data'].items():
...         print(coin, data['id'])
...
BTC 1
ETH 1027
```

We can remove some boilerplate from the body of the loop by using `map(json.loads, ...)`, and since you know there is only one item in the dict, you can get fancy and use iterable unpacking:

```
>>> for response in map(json.loads, info_2_response):
...     [(coin, data), *_] = response['data'].items()
...     print(coin, data['id'])
...
BTC 1
ETH 1027
```

And if you *expect* there to only be one, you might want an error thrown, so you can do:

```
>>> for response in map(json.loads, info_2_response):
...     [(coin, data)] = response['data'].items()
...     print(coin, data['id'])
...
BTC 1
ETH 1027
```

So note, in the top version, `[(coin, data), *_] = response['data'].items()` will not fail if there is more than one item in the dict, the rest of the items get assigned to a list called `_`, which we are ignoring. But that's just a conventional name for a "throwaway" variable.

However, the other version would fail:

```
>>> response
{'status': {'timestamp': '2023-01-25T22:59:59.087Z', 'error_code': 0, 'error_message': None, 'elapsed': 16, 'credit_count': 1, 'notice': None}, 'data': {'ETH': {'id': 1027, 'name': 'Ethereum', 'symbol': 'ETH'}}}
>>> response['data']['FOO'] = "FOO STUFF"
>>> [(coin, data)] = response['data'].items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the `data` dictionary only has a single key, you can do something like this:

```
import json

info_2_response = [
    """{"status": {"timestamp": "2023-01-25T22:59:58.760Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 16, "credit_count": 1, "notice": null},
    "data": {"BTC": {"id": 1, "name": "Bitcoin", "symbol": "BTC"}}}""",
    """{"status": {"timestamp": "2023-01-25T22:59:59.087Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 16, "credit_count": 1, "notice": null},
    "data": {"ETH": {"id": 1027, "name": "Ethereum", "symbol": "ETH"}}}""",
]
for response in info_2_response:
    info_2_dict = json.loads(response)
    print(list(info_2_dict["data"].values())[0]["id"])
```

This will print:

```
1
1027
```

The code works by using the `.values()` method of a dictionary to get a list of values. Since there's only a single value, we just take the first item from the list and then look up the `id` attribute.

We can expand the compound statement to make the operations a little more clear:

```
for response in info_2_response:
    info_2_dict = json.loads(response)
    all_values = info_2_dict["data"].values()
    first_value = list(all_values)[0]
    id = first_value["id"]
    print(id)
```