# get Key by value, dict, python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

How can I get a key from a value?

my dict:

```
countries = {
        "Normal UK project" : "1",
        "UK Omnibus project" : "1-Omni",
        "Nordic project" : ["11","12","13","14"],
        "German project" : "21",
        "French project" : "31"
        }
```

my semi functioning code:

```
for k, v in countries.items():
    if "1" in v:
        print k
```

expected output:

```
Normal UK project
```

actual output:

```
French project
UK Omnibus project
German project
Normal UK project
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: `if "1" == v:`?

Comment: if the value I am looking for is "12" then it would fail

Comment: First, you should unify the type of your values. Some are strings, some are lists. Better use only lists (some with just one element), then your code would actually work.

Comment: Yes but is that the right thing to do?

Comment: If you often find yourself trying to get the key from the value, perhaps the dictionary is the wrong way around?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: @Boosted_d16: Yet it *should* fail for `"German project"` and `"French project"`? Are you looking for `str.startswith()` instead here perhaps?

Comment: As a side note: Looking for "12" gives "Nordic Project" (in Python 3.4).

Comment: @nofinator - not a duplicate, my dict does not have a 1 to 1 relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the types of the values in the dictionary are not the same, making it much more difficult to use the dictionary, not only in this scenario. While Python allows this, you really should consider unifying the types in the dictionary, e.g. make them all lists. You can do so in just one line of code:

```
countries = {key: val if isinstance(val, list) else [val] 
                        for key, val in countries.items()}
```

Now, each single string is wrapped into a list and your existing code will work correctly.

Alternatively, if you have to use the dictionary in it's current form, you can adapt your lookup function:

```
for k, v in countries.items():
    if "1" == v or isinstance(v, list) and "1" in v:
        print k
```

Answer (score 8):

`c={}` - any dict

a(value) - need know this key

```
key=list(c.keys())[list(c.values()).index(a)]
```

Comment: This works but `.index()` will only return the first instance of `a` in `c`

Answer (score 4):

The following code provide another and short version of getting dictionary keys by some value, by using list comprehensions and dic.items():

```
keys_have_value = [k for k,v in dic.items() if v=="1"]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged as they show poor attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
def keys_of_value(dct, value):
    for k in dct:
        if isinstance(dct[k], list):
            if value in dct[k]:
                return k
        else:
            if value == dct[k]:
                return k

assert keys_of_value(countries, "12") == "Nordic project"
assert keys_of_value(countries, "1")  == "Normal UK project"
```

If you want me to shorten it a little bit, I might do

```
from operator import eq, contains

def keys_of_value(dct, value, ops = (eq, contains)):
    for k in dct:
        if ops[isinstance(dct[k], list)](dct[k], value):
            return k

assert keys_of_value(countries, "12") == "Nordic project"
assert keys_of_value(countries, "1") == "Normal UK project"
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your semi-functioning code is returning the other values because with entries like:

```
    "Normal UK project" : "1",
```

..then `"1" in v` checks if the string contains the "1" character, whereas with entries like:

```
    "Nordic project" : ["11","12","13","14"],
```

..then it will check if the list contains an element "1".

The `in` operator works on both strings and lists, but in a different manner:

```
>>> "1" in "123"
True
>>> "1" in ["123", "blah"]
False
>>> "1" in ["1", "blah"]
True
```

Ideally your data would be more consistent - all lists, or all strings:

```
countries = {
        "Normal UK project" : ["1"],
        "UK Omnibus project" : ["1-Omni"],
        "Nordic project" : ["11","12","13","14"],
        "German project" : ["21"],
        "French project" : ["31"]
        }

for k, v in countries.items():
    if "1" in v:
        print k
```

Comment: I was going to do this but I was not sure if that was the right thing to do as it seemed a bit redundant to have a list of one item.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think using `in` and the function `values` is easier.

```
print 1 in {1:"123", 2:"blah"}
print "blah" in {1:"123", 2:"blah"}.values()
```

Output is:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_Value(dic,value):
    for name in dic:
        if dic[name] == value:
            return name
```