# How to get the keys from value in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve question. which gives following output:

```
>>> frequency([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14])
```

ANSWER: `([7], [13, 14])`

Basically it's returning list of HIGHEST and LOWEST frequency.

I'm using collection.Counter() function So I got this:

```
Counter({13: 4, 14: 4, 11: 2, 12: 2, 7: 1})
```

I extracted key and values and I also got my values sorted in one list. Now I want to get keys which are having least and highest values so that I can generate list from that.

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get Key by value, dict, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295315/get-key-by-value-dict-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the minimum and maximum values first, then build the list of keys at those values with *list comprehensions*:

```
c =  Counter({13: 4, 14: 4, 11: 2, 12: 2, 7: 1})
values = c.values()
mn, mx = min(values), max(values)
mins = [k for k, v in c.items() if v == mn]
maxs = [k for k, v in c.items() if v == mx]
print (mins, maxs)
# ([7], [13, 14])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most pythonic way, but easy to understand for the beginner.

```
from collections import Counter
L = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]

answer_min = []
answer_max = []

d = Counter(L)
min_value = min(d.values())
max_value = max(d.values())

for k,v in d.items():

    if v == min_value:
        answer_min.append(k)
    if v == max_value:
        answer_max.append(k)

answer = (answer_min, answer_max)
answer
```

Gives us `([7], [13, 14])`. It looks like you only needed to know about `dictionary.items()` to solve this.

Comment: The `elif` should be `if`, to handle the case where `min_value` and `max_value` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import collections
s = [13,12,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14]
count = collections.Counter(s)
mins = [a for a, b in count.items() if b == min(count.values())]
maxes = [a for a, b in count.items() if b == max(count.values())]
final_vals = [mins, maxes]
```

Output:

```
[[7], [13, 14]]
```

Comment: I think this will recalculate `min(count.values())` once for every item in the list comprehension, which is unnecessarily slow.