# remove a dict entry in a list of dict python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

How can I remove a key in a dic in a list

for exemple

```
My_list= [{'ID':0,'Name':'Paul','phone':'1234'},{'ID':1,'Name':'John','phone':'5678'}]
```

I want to remove in ID 1 the phone key

```
My_list= [{'ID':0,'Name':'Paul','phone':'1234'},{'ID':1,'Name':'John'}]
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [get key by value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through the list, check whether if 'ID' equals to 1 and if so then delete the 'phone' key. This should work:

```
for d in My_list:
    if d["ID"] == 1:
        del d["phone"]
```

And finally print the list:

```
print My_list
```

Answer (score 0):

When the id you are looking for matches `1`, then reconstruct the dictionary excluding the key `phone`, otherwise use the dictionary as it is, like this

```
l = [{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Paul', 'phone': '1234'},
     {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'phone': '5678'}]

k, f = 1, {"phone"}
print([{k: i[k] for k in i.keys() - f} if i["ID"] == k else i for i in l])
# [{'phone': '1234', 'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Paul'}, {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John'}]
```

Here, `k` is the value of ID you are looking for and `f` is a set of keys which need to be excluded in the resulting dictionary, if the id matches.

Comment: >>> print[{k: i[k] for k in i.viewkeys() - f} if i["ID"] == k else i for i in l]
I have 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   I use Python 3.x

Comment: @user3224813 If you are using Python 3.x, please check the updated answer. Also, you need to explicitly mention the version in the question. That would be good for the answerers.