# dictionary of dictionaries, get keys in common for values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, return-value

I have a very big dictionary of dictionaries and it is like this:

```
Dict={,
    ...
    '25465466':{'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate0', 'Board': 'easyBoard06', 'Branch': 'branchController05', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_4', 'Channel': 'channel003\n'},
    '436232302': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_03:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate1', 'Board': 'easyBoard01', 'Branch': 'branchController05', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8', 'Channel': 'channel002\n'},
    '470311412': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_03:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate0', 'Board': 'easyBoard00', 'Branch': 'branchController05', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_4', 'Channel': 'channel003\n'},
    ...
}
```

And if the user types `cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN` or `easyCrate1/easyBoard01` or more combination of this values the script has to return those keys (numbers like '654546536') that they have in common.

For example if input is `easyCrate0/CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_4` the answer is `470311412,25465466`.

Comment: When do you use the keys within the inner dictionary? Currently with the way you have it set up, you can only access the inner dictionary (with keys such as "Cmstrk" and "Crate") with keys such as "25465466". Are you wanting to have the user input something like "cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN" then return a number such as "25465466" or vice versa?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: yes i want to know the keys in common to some values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = "easyCrate0/CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_4".split("/")
common = []
for k in Dict:
    if all(x in Dict[k].values() for x in inp): # if all of the values match the user input, add it to common list
        common.append(k) 
print (common)
['25465466', '470311412']
```

You could also use sets:

```
common = []
for k in Dict:
    if len(set(inp).intersection(Dict[k].values())) == len(inp):
        common.append(k)
```

You can use  a list comp also:

```
common = [k  for k in Dict if len(set(inp).intersection(Dict[k].values())) == len(inp)]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works, but theres a detail, it returns several times the same key, and it returns keys from value1 or value2, instead of the key in common between value1 and value2

Comment: so you want the keys that that have both elements?

Comment: the keys that both elementes have in common (if they have any)

Comment: I am pretty sure that is what my code is doing.it gets the keys that have all the inputted values

Comment: yes it works thanks a lot!!, just to say, i used the sets option, since the first one repeats the answer, but anyway thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help.

```
Dict = {
'25465466':{'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate0', 'Board': 'easyBoard06', 'Branch': 'branchController05', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_4', 'Channel': 'channel003\n'},

'436232302': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_03:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate1', 'Board': 'easyBoard01', 'Branch': 'branchController05', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_8', 'Channel': 'channel002\n'},

'470311412': {'Cmstrk': 'cms_trk_dcs_03:CAEN', 'Crate': 'easyCrate0', 'Board': 'easyBoard00', 'Branch': 'branchController05', 'TrackerSY': 'CMS_TRACKER_SY1527_4', 'Channel': 'channel003\n'}
}

def sub_search(terms):
    check = lambda k: all(map(lambda term:term in Dict[k].values(), terms))
    return [key for key,value in Dict.items() if check(key)]

def search(term):
    terms = term.split('/')
    return sub_search(terms)

search('cms_trk_dcs_05:CAEN')
#['25465466']

search('easyCrate1/easyBoard01')
#['436232302']
```

Answer (score 0):

FINAL EDIT:
Here is the code cleaner:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

find = raw_input("What are you looking for? ")
finder = find.split('/')

similar = []
for key in Dict:
    for x in range(0, len(finder)):
        for pairs in Dict[key].items():
            if pairs[1] == finder[0]: 
                similar.append(key)

if len(similar) == 1 or len(finder) == 1:
    print ",".join(similar) 
for items in similar:
    similar.remove(items)
print ",".join(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(similar)))
```