# Python check the whole loop before going to the else statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

How do I run through the whole loop and then after go to `else` statement, if the `if` condition is false?

The output is:

> No
>
> No
>
> Yes

But I only want it to jump to the else statement if all of the values does not equal!

```
test_1 = (255, 200, 100)
test_2 = (200, 200, 100)
test_3 = (500, 50, 200)

dict = {"test_1":test_1,
        "test_2":test_2,
        "test_3":test_3}


for item in dict:
   if dict[item] == (500, 50, 200):
        print('Yes')
   else:
        print('No')
```

So basicly the output should say, because one of the values was true.

> Yes

Comment: FWIW, your question seems to have changed from 'How can I check if a dictionary contains a value?' to 'How can I extract the key associated with a value in a dict, if one exists?'.  If that's correct, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run the loop until you find a matche. You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function for this purpose, like this

```
if any(dict_object[key] == (500, 50, 200) for key in dict_object):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

We pass a generator expression to `any` function. The generator expression takes each and every item from the dict and checks if it is equal to `(500, 50, 200)`. The moment it finds a match, the `any` will return `True` immediately and the rest of the iterations will not even take place. If none of the items match `(500, 50, 200)`, `any` will return `False` and the `No` will be printed.

---

**Edit:** After a lengthy discussion with the OP in the chat, he actually wanted to know the item which matches as well. So, the better solution would be to go with `for..else` like in the other answer by NPE, like this

```
for key in dict_object:
   if key.startswith('test_') and dict_object[key] == (500, 50, 200):
        # Make use of `dict_object[key]` and `key` here
        break
else:
    print('No matches')
```

Comment: clean and simple, a great answer! :)

Comment: Using this method, how would I print(item), since it's not referenced apparently?

Comment: @Frederik You know the item you are searching for. So if there is a match, you can simply print it, right?

Comment: `item` is a really bad name (from OP's original) for what is actually the `key`

Comment: @thefourtheye Not actually, if I had test_3_id:2 in the dict :/

Comment: @Frederik I am sorry, I didn't understand that. Can you please explain?

Comment: `if any(dict[item] == (500, 50, 200) for item in dict): 
    print(dict[item]['id'])`
I didn't show it, in the post, because I didn't know it would be a problem.
@thefourtheye

Comment: @Frederik Your dicts have just tuples as values. Can you please show the actual structure and what exactly you are trying to do? If that is entirely changes the meaning, then you may have to create another question :(

Comment: Not if I don't know it's `(500,50,200)`. What if `(500,50,200)` it's a input from the user?

Comment: @Frederik That will be stored in a variable I suppose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68588/discussion-between-frederik-and-thefourtheye).

Answer (score 4):

> But I only want it to jump to the else statement if all of the values does not equal!

Python's `for`-`else` construct can be used to do exactly that:

```
for item in dict:
   if dict[item] == (500, 50, 200):
        print('Yes')
        break
else:
    print('No')
```

For further discussion, see [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

However, in this particular instance I would not use an explicit loop at all:

```
print ("Yes" if (500, 50, 200) in dict.values() else "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `in` operator:

```
item_appears_in_dict = item in dict.values()
print "Yes" if item_appears_in_dict else "No"
```

Comment: As it stands this throws a syntax error.  the second `print` in the second line shouldn't be there, as the ternary operator allows expressions but not statements.