# Python: Selecting the appropriate type from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, list, select, types

How to manage the following:

```
listing = db.query("SELECT list_id FROM results limit 10")
```

returns a list containing values converted to long type : ({'list_id': 175L},...)

```
element = db.query("SELECT * FROM list LIMIT 1")
```

returns returns a single element which has a standard int id : element['id'] = 175

Now i would like to do something like this:

```
if element['id'] not in listing:
   print "ok"
```

But the loop is never entered. I think it is because of the different types in the list (long) and element (int).

Is there a quick and simple solution to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first query returns list of dictionaries. You are trying to find a value in dictionary. Here is correct way how to iterate through keys in a dictionary:

```
for name, age in list.iteritems():
    if age == search_age:
        print name
```

Taken from here: [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)