# get the key based on value in a dictionary (where keys might be duplicated) of python

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I'm new to python. I have the following task to iterate all pairs of the values of a dictionary to calculate a value (hamming distance of the two sequences (each value pair is a sequence pair)). Then, I need to print out the corresponding keys if the hamming distance calculated is 1. The code is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming

graph=[]
i=5
t1=tuple('aaaaa')
t2=tuple('aaaab')
t3=tuple('aaaac')
t4=tuple('aaaad')
t5=tuple('aaaaa')

population={'1':t1, '2':t2, '3':t3, '4':t4, '5':t5}

for pair in itertools.combinations(np.array(population.values()),2):
    if hamming(pair[0],pair[1])*i==1: graph.append(str(population.keys()[population.values().index(pair[0])]) +'\t' + str(population.keys()[population.values().index(pair[1])]) +'n')

print graph
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    if hamming(pair[0],pair[1])*len==1: graph.append(str(population.keys()[population.values().index(pair[0])]) +'\t' + str(population.keys()[population.values().index(pair[1])]) +'n')
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any comment is greatly appreciated. 
Edit: I learned to access the key from the value of a dictionary from this link:
[Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)
Edit: to avoid the variable to be built-in.

Comment: Hint for the future: it's generally nice to not only give the error you received, but also *where* the error occurred. Otherwise we answerers need to comb through your code before even beginning to understand what the problem is. Good luck!

Comment: Don't try to do so much on one line. That long line you have there is an unreadable monstrosity. Besides making the code more readable, splitting the line up will help you by making the line reported in the traceback more specific.

Comment: And if you're using the dictionary to find a key based on the value, then your dictionary is reversed and you should swap the keys and values.

Comment: Also please don't name your variables like built-in functions (`len`).

Comment: @interjay, I understand. I thought about this. But I cannot. Because the keys are supposed to be distinct, while in my case, I need duplicate keys.

Comment: @qaz Don't worry too much about that for now. Focus on breaking down the code into simpler statements to pinpoint where that error is occurring, and it'll be easier to find out why.

Comment: If you don't convert `population.values()` to a `np.array` the code runs without error, but I'm not sure if it does what you want.

Comment: What if the values are not unique, as in this case? `t5` has the same value as `t1`.

Comment: I've found another way to get around this situation by switching the keys and values and using a list of integers instead of an integer as the value. But still, I would be greatly appreciated if you know how to fix the above code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the comparison of dissimilar types and can be demonstrated with a simpler script:

```
import numpy as np
mytuple = ('a', 'a')
myarray = np.array(mytuple)
[myarray].index(mytuple)
```

When run, you get:

$ python hem.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hem.py", line 4, in <module>
    [myarray].index(mytuple)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`population.values()` is a list of tuples but pair[0] is an np array, so they will never compare properly. The error itself is a confusing, but you'll need a different way to find the index.