# Python printing single key/value pairs from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

Say I have the following code that makes a dict:

```
x = 0
myHash = {}
name = ["Max","Fred","Alice","Bobby"]

while x <= 3:
    myHash[name[x]] = x
    x += 1

l = sorted(myHash.values(), reverse=True)
largestNum = l[0]

# print myHash.getKeyFromValue(largestNum)
```

Is it possible to easily get the key that is paired to my `largestNum` variable without looping through the entire dict? Something like the pseudo code in the line at the bottom.

Note: I don't want to get a value from a key. I want the reverse of that.

Comment: Another way to get `myHash` dict: `{i: j for j, i in enumerate(name)}`

Comment: To make your question more clear: are you interested in specifically finding the key from the largest value? Or are you interested in generally finding a key from an arbitrary value?

Comment: Getting the key from the largest value solves my current problem. But it would be nice to know a general way to find a key from an arbitrary value.

Comment: @Sam: Unless the values are unique, you have no means of identifying a unique key which corresponded to the value found.

Comment: An idea from question [get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary):  `largest_value = max(myHash.values()); [name for name, index in myHash.items() if index == largest_value]`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, that's true. In this particular case I can guarantee that my values are unique. But I understand that this means a more general solution may not be possible.

Comment: @Sam: I gave the basic setup below. Still requires the values to be hashable (otherwise they're not legal keys), but it maintains `O(1)` expected lookup costs.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. It is a great solution for my specific problem. I'll accept it as the answer when StackOverflow lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just sort the `values`. Sort the `items` by their `values`, and get the key for free.

```
from operator import itemgetter

l = sorted(myHash.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
largestKey, largestNum = l[0]
```

Note: If you only want the largest value, not the rest of the sort results, you can save some work and skip the full `sorted` work (reducing work from `O(n log n)` to `O(n)`):

```
largestKey, largestNum = max(myHash.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

For the general case of inverting a `dict`, if the values are unique, it's trivial to create a reversed mapping:

```
invert_dict = {v: k for k, v in orig_dict.items()}
```

If the values aren't unique, and you want to find all keys corresponding to a single value with a single lookup, you'd invert to a multi-dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

invert_dict = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in orig_dict.items():
    invert_dict[v].add(k)
# Optionally convert back to regular dict to avoid lookup auto-vivification in the future:
# invert_dict = dict(invert_dict)
```

Comment: Side-note: If you're in Python 2.7, use `viewitems` and `viewvalues` instead of `items` and `values` to avoid making intermediate `list`s. It also means the `2to3` converter will convert the usage directly (because `viewitems` and `viewvalues` are directly equivalent to the Py3 version of `items` and `values`). Same goes for `keys`/`viewkeys`, but usually, if you're just iterating `dict` keys, iterate directly, no method call at all.

Comment: If you don't have duplicate value in dictionary's value then you can use this approach;
.......
.....#find max value from your values of dictionary
.....dictValue = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}ValuesList = dictValue.values()
.....KeyList = dictValue.keys()
.....MaxValue = max(ValuesList)
.....YourReqKey = KeyList[ValuesList.index(MaxValue)]