# Get dictionary key by value if value is list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So this is related to a shorter question posted here earlier: [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

I adapted the example that the values be `list`s of `int`. Say I had this,

```
mydict = {'george':[1,2,3],'amber':[18,19]}
```

then I could output `"amber"` by:

```
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index([18,19])])
```

Is there a way to adjust this so I can output `"amber"` by "asking" for just one item of the list? i.e. e.g. `19`?

*Summary*: I want to ask my dictionary: "Give me the key that has in its value(list) the item "19"

Comment: if you have to do this often, you have a design problem.  You're really supposed to go the *other* way, from `key` -> `value`

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The data structure at hand requires me this time to try it the other way round. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a conditional

```
>>> mydict = {'george':[1,2,3],'amber':[18,19]}
>>> [i for i in mydict if 19 in mydict[i]]
['amber']
```

Here you get a list of all the keys that has in its value a list with the item 19.

If you want only the first element you can use `[i for i in mydict if 19 in mydict[i]][0]`

Another innovative way would be using `filter`

```
>>> filter(lambda x: 19 in x[1], mydict.items())
[('amber', [18, 19])]
```

Note that here you get both the key and value as a pair.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer from the question you linked:

```
for name, l in mydict.iteritems():
    if 19 in l:
        print name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to search many times, building a lookup to index directly will be faster:

```
mydict = {'george':[1,2,3],'amber':[18,19]}
lookup = dict((number, name) for name, numbers in mydict.items() for number in numbers)
print lookup[19]
```

A drawback is this index needs to be rebuilt or updated if `mydict` changes.