# Simplest way of grabbing key associated with 'max' value in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have searched for ways of grabbing an associated key based on a value, but most seem very complicated. It may be because I'm new at Python, but is there an easy way to get a key associated with a (max) value?  For example:

```
d = {'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3, 'four':4, 'five':5}
max(d.values())
```

will give 5.

How do I get the key associated with that value of '5'?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the dictionary and save the key of the highest value.

```
import math

max_value = -math.inf  # Infinitly small number.
max_value_key = None
for key, value in d.items():
    if max_value < value:
        max_value = value
        max_value_key = key
```

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work.  I found a solution on here from another user, but I truly don't understand how it works:

maximum = max(d, key=d.get)  
print(maximum, d[maximum])

So with my example, this would return the 5 value since it's the max, and will return the key associated with 5, that being 'five.'  If I were to break down the solution, and just do maximum = max(d), it will return 'two'.  I guess I'm not understanding the get method?  I don't know, i'm so confused trying to break this down to understand it...

Comment: Just print `max_value_key` and you'll see this method works. `maximum = max(d, key=d.get)` is better though. The key option is a function each element in `d` is passed into. The elements in `d` are the keys and `d.get` will return the value of each key. So `max(d, key=d.get)` will see which key in your dictionary which have the greatest value and give you the corresponding key. When you do `max(d)` you're looking for the greatest key in the dictionary, and since they all are strings it'll give you the string which is greatest in alphabetical order.