# How to find Key by user inputting Value

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function where the Key of a dictionary is printed when the user inputs one of its values.

My dictionary is:

```
student = {c0952: [18, 'John', 'Smith'],
           c0968: [24, 'Sarah', 'Kelly']
           }
```

For for example if the user inputs 'John' then the student number c0952 will print.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do in case of equal values. I doubt that there will be only one 'John'.

Comment: the point of dictionaries is to look up values from a key, if you want to look up stuff from the person's name then make the name the key. (possibly as a separate dictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: i understand there might be equal values, however for this small project i am working on there is only one 'John'.

Comment: Then: `print [x for x in student.keys() if 'John' in student[x]][0]`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
student = { 'c0952': [18, 'John', 'Smith'],
            'c0968': [24, 'Sarah', 'Kelly']
          }

name_value = raw_input("value? ")

for stu_num, names in student.iteritems():
    for name in names:
        if name == name_value:
            print stu_num
```

Or, as [akg mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564272/how-to-find-key-by-user-inputting-value/42564465#comment72262854_42564272), a one-liner using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehension):

```
print [x for x in student.keys() if name_value in student[x]][0]
```

Demo:

> value? John
>   c0952

Using most of the answer from [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary).