# How to get a key from a list of dictionaries by its value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, reverse-lookup

I have a list of dictionaries and I am trying to get the dictionary key by its value:

```
list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
         {'d':4,'e':5,'f':6},
         {'g':7,'h':8,'i':9}]
```

Here I am trying to get the dictionary key if the value `5`  exists in the list of dictionaries.

Comment: What result are you expecting if multiple keys have the target value? Does it differ if the keys are in different dictionaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Get key by value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: @FallenAngel that question is asking about a single dictionary, not a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus so? Go through the list and look up in each dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for dic in list1:
    for key in dic:
        if dic[key] == search_value:
            print key
```

Comment: Please don't name a variable `list`. It's even worse when the variable named `list` is actually a `dict`.

Comment: This isn't entirely wrong, but it's bad style. #1, don't use reserved words like `list` as variable names, that can collide with built in methods in confusing ways. #2, the contents of `list1` are dicts rather than lists, so `for list in list1` is both misleading and mildly unsafe - only mildly because direct use of the `list` constructor is rare. It also assumes child dicts of exactly one comparable value, which may or may not be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641204/how-to-get-a-dictionary-key-by-its-value#comment72409822_42641204) by Peter DeGlopper:

> What result are you expecting if multiple keys have the target value? Does it differ if the keys are in different dictionaries?

However, if for example you want a list of 2-tuples `(i, k)` – where `i` is the index (in the list) of the dictionary where the value is found, and `k` is the key associated with the value – the following works:

```
def index_keys(data, value):
    return [(i, k) for i, d in enumerate(data) for k, v in d.items() if v == value]
```

Examples:

```
>>> list1 = [
...     {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},
...     {'d':4,'e':5,'f':6},
...     {'g':7,'h':8,'i':9}
... ]
>>> index_keys(list1, 5)
[(1, 'e')]
>>> list1[1]['e'] == 5
True
```

```
>>> list2 = [
...     {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
...     {'w': 2, 'x': 4, 'y': 6, 'z': 8},
...     {'a': 6, 'b': 6, 'y': 6, 'z': 8}
... ]
>>> index_keys(list2, 2)
[(0, 'b'), (1, 'w')]
>>> index_keys(list2, 8)
[(1, 'z'), (2, 'z')]
>>> index_keys(list2, 6)
[(1, 'y'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'y'), (2, 'b')]
```

Comment: Now my current scenario is to get the value of a particular key from the dictionary where it has different keys.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are distinct over all the dictionaries as they are here, you can build a reverse lookup dictionary:

```
reverselookup = {}
for d in list1:
    reverselookup.update({v: k for k, v in d.items()})
```

You can then use this to find the keys corresponding to a value by indexing the dictionary:

```
>>> reverselookup[5]
'e'
```

If the values are not distinct, but the keys are, you can build a list of corresponding keys instead.

```
import collections
reverselookup = collections.defaultdict(list)
for d in list1:
    for v, k in d.items():
        reverselookup[v].append(k)
```