# How to predict key from its value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose we have list like this:

```
tokens=["apple":1,"zebra":2]
```

Then how to find apple using value 1?

Comment: There can be *multiple* keys that map on the same value...

Comment: Furthermore you write something between a dictionary and a list. This is not valid Python.

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: Thanks you all guys for helping me. Specially thanks to @Burnie777.