# How to get the key from a given value in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How to get the key from a given value in a Python dictionary?

For example, if I have:

```
d = {
        'Italy' : ['IT', 'ITA'],
        'Austria' : ['AT'],
    }

search = 'ITA'
```

What code is needed if I want this to return Italy. Notice that values can be lists

So if I search for *AT*, it should return *Austria*.

*IT* or *ITA* should return *Italy*.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary) but you could invert the dictionary with this code:

```
d_inv = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        d_inv[i] = k
```

And then use:

```
d_inv[search]
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I was checking the original link of my duplicate, and that would have worked if no list were present in the values.