# string number average returned in string format

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, key-value

Here are some tests:

Input: `"zero nine five two"`

Output: `"four"`

Input: `"four six two three"`

Ouput: `"three"`

Here is my code, which works until the last step where I need to inverse lookup key by value, which I dont know how to do. Any advice?

```
def average_string(s):
    num_dic = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 
    'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9}
    str_split = s.split()
    int_values = []
    for key, val in num_dic.items():
        if key in str_split: 
            int_values.append(val)
            int_avg = int(sum(int_values) / len(int_values))
    return int_avg
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-invert-a-mapping

Comment: Also you can calculate your average with following code: `int(sum([num_dic[s] for s in str_split]) / len(str_split))`

Comment: Do you ever expect to have a word of a digit get input into your function twice? lfor example: `"two zero nine five two"`

Comment: To perform a lookup, rather than attempting to reverse the entire dictionary, I would use items() or iteritems() as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary). That is, unless there is future value in switching the keys,values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: Just return  `return {v: k for k, v in num_dic.items()}[int_avg]` instead of `int_avg`, note dictionaries are not intended to work this way though.

Comment: Just because OP asked about reversing a dict doesn't mean it's the best solution for him. This question shouldn't be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
num_dic = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9}

s = "zero nine five two"

new_dict = {b:a for a, b in num_dic.items()}

average = sum(num_dic[i] for i in s.split())/float(len(s.split()))

final_average = new_dict[average]
```

Output:

```
four
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just utilize a list of words to represent the numbers where the index represents their respective value?

```
def average_string(s):
    num_list = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
    str_split = s.split()
    int_sum = sum(map(num_list.index, str_split))
    return num_list[int_sum / len(str_split)]
```

The map goes over each element in `str_split` and translates it into the numeric version by calling `num_list.index()` using each element as a parameter.

Finally using the same `num_list`, use the average value as the index to get the string version back.

Comment: How about `return num_list[int_sum // len(str_split)]` (or worse, `return num_list[int(round(1.0 * int_sum / len(str_split)))]`) to allow it to work in both Python2 and Python 3 since OP didn't specify a version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you inverse a dictionary. This is a duplicated question though:

```
inv_dic = {v: k for k, v in num_dic.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to lookup in a dict by value. Instead you can loop over the dict to find the correct value like this:

```
for text, number in num_dic.iteritems():
    if number == int_avg:
        print text
```

Here is another question where you can find this: [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

You can use `num_dic.items()` in Python 3