# Get the most currently dated subset of data from a Python dict with multiple dated dicts within

Tags: python, date, dictionary, nested, max

In Python, is there a good way (programmatically) to get the value of `["win"]["amount"]` from the subset of data where the **most recent date** exists?

To provide a more concrete example of what I'm asking, I'd like the `amount` for `win` from April 2, 2018 (`2018-04-02`), which would be `199.51`.

This is the source JSON (I convert this to a Python `dict` using `json.loads`):

```
{
    "numbers": [{
        "lose": {
            "amount": "122.50"
        },
        "win": {
            "amount": "232.50"
        },
        "date": "2018-01-08"
    }, {
        "lose": {
            "amount": "233.75"
        },
        "win": {
            "amount": "216.25"
        },
        "date": "2018-03-05"
    }, {
        "lose": {
            "amount": "123.50"
        },
        "win": {
            "amount": "543.00"
        },
        "date": "2018-03-12"
    }, {
        "lose": {
            "amount": "213.31"
        },
        "win": {
            "amount": "253.33"
        },
        "date": "2018-03-19"
    }, {
        "lose": {
            "amount": "217.00"
        },
        "win": {
            "amount": "199.51"
        },
        "date": "2018-04-02"
    }]
}
```

This seems like a very simple solution is in order, but I cannot quite nail down what that solution is, or if there is a Pythonic way of accomplishing this. I did write some logic to calculate the largest date by putting all of the dates into a list called `datelist` and doing a `max(datelist)`, but I'm not sure how to relate that back to get `["amount"]["win"]`.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I'm going to respond to that question objectively:

Yes, when I put the dates into `datelist` and calculated the most recent using `max()`, as stated. But, I'm not entirely sure how to relate that calculation back to getting the `amount` I am trying to get. I was thinking the best thing to do would be to somehow search the `dict` by value instead of key. I tried something like this, but to no avail (I think because date is "outside" of `win` and `lose`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: The solution from @juanpa-arrivillaga (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724192/9616920) worked for me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `'date'` attributes follow ISO 8601 so the lexicographical order corresponds to the chronological order then you can simply use `max` with an appropriate `key`, so:

```
In [12]: max(data['numbers'], key=lambda d:d['date'])['win']['amount']
Out[12]: '199.51'
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Looks like I need to brush up on anonymous lambda functions.

Comment: @stuntmachine you could just as easily use a normal function

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this anonymous function returns the subset of data shared w/ the max date, and then it's as simple as choosing `['win']['amount']` from that result. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your dates are in ISO 8601 notation you can do simple string compare as a sorting mechanism for your inner `numbers` list and then pick up the last element:

```
import operator

oldest = sorted(your_data["numbers"], key=operator.itemgetter("date"))[0]["win"]["amount"]
# 232.50
newest = sorted(your_data["numbers"], key=operator.itemgetter("date"))[-1]["win"]["amount"]
# 199.51
```

Or just sort the inner list once and then pick up whichever element you want if you need to access them more often.