# Dictionary in Python and key with value

Tags: python

I have to create a program which will print a greeting only to friendly bears. I have created this program but it gives me all the bears, the angry ones too.

```
bears = {"Grizzly":"angry", "Brown":"friendly", "Polar":"friendly"}
for bear in bears:
  if "[bear]:friendly":
   print("Hello, "+bear+" bear!")
else:
  print("odd")
```

Comment: `if "[bear]:friendly":` what do you think this is doing?

Comment: Also, make sure your indentation is meaningful. I'm guessing you wanted an `if/else` statement, not a `for/else`.

Comment: I think this is considering if the key is friendly

Comment: @Joaquin you need `if bears[bear] == 'friendly':`

Comment: The indentation is OK because this is the one that one teacher gave us.

Comment: Thank you Ev! But could you explain me why?

Comment: @Joaquin, please read up on dictionaries in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: I mean, @Ev.Kounis , why do you need to use "bears[bear]"

Comment: the term `for bear in bears` means iterate through each item in the list `bears` and assign it temporarily to `bear` and `bears[bear]` gives the value of `bear`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: Your current edit has nothing in common with the original question. What are you doing? If you want to ask a new question, ask a *new* question. I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a better idea to iterate over `dict`'s keys' and values by `items()` method (or `iteritems()` if you are using `python2`):

```
for bear_name, status in bears.items():  # get key and value for bear
    if status == 'friendly':
        print("Hello, " + bear_name + " bear!")
```

And polar bears are usually not friendly.

Comment: Answers are generally expected to have some explanation to go along with them

Answer (score 0):

You can  use this approach :

```
bears = {"Grizzly":"angry", "Brown":"friendly", "Polar":"friendly"}

for i,j in bears.items():
    if j=="friendly":
        print("Hello, " + i + " bear!")
    else:
        print('odd')
```

output:

```
odd
Hello, Polar bear!
Hello, Brown bear!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, which should give you the output you want:

```
for bear in bears:
if bears[bear] == "friendly":
    print("Hello, " + bear + " bear!")
else:
    print("odd")
```