# Get the key that has specific attribute of its value

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have dictionary with list of objects as values.

```
class Device_Terminals():
    """Class for define object for each device"""
    def __init__(self, device_name, source, drain):
        self.device_name = device_name
        self.source = source
        self.drain = drain

device = Device_Terminals(line[0], line[1], line[3])
if line[2] not in devices_dict:
        devices_dict[line[2]] = []
devices_dict[line[2]].append(device)
```

I want to return the key whose one of its objects has specific name, the dictionary looks like this

```
{A1:[ MNA1 X_N1 VSS, MPA1_1 X X_P1_1, MPA1_2 X X_P1_2, MPA1_3 X X_P1_3, MPA1_4 X X_P1_4, MPA1_5 X X_P1_5, MPA1_6 X X_P1_6, MPA1_7 X X_P1_7], 'A3': [MNA3 X_N1 VSS, MPA3_1 X_P2_1 VDD, MPA3_2 X_P2_2 VDD, MPA3_3 X_P2_3 VDD, MPA3_4 X_P2_4 VDD, MPA3_5 X_P2_5 VDD]}
```

each element of the lists is an object. 
how can I return the key whose value of the

```
 device_name == MPA3_3: 
   return key
```

Comment: Please explain better what you’re looking for? Like what is `line` and what exactly you mean by `object` I’m not sure I fully understand where you’re going with this question.

Comment: What does the dictionary `device_dict` look like?

Comment: What is `device_dict`? You're question is not very clear. Please provide a reproductible example and a clear explanation of your issue, so other will be able to help  you.

Comment: I edited the question @Ananth

Comment: Can you please show the code that you use to construct the dictionary. Your data does not make sense as dicts have key value pairs. I don't see that in your update. Dicts are usually presented as `{key: value, key: value}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: when I am trying to print it it looks like this  {'A1': [<__main__.Device_Terminals instance at 0x7fce0b42ba70>, <__main__.Device_Terminals instance at 0x7fce0b42bb48>, <__main__.Device_Terminals instance at 0x7fce0b42bc20>]

Comment: This is a dictionary with only one key (`A1`) and whose value is a list of `Device_Terminal` objects: where is the dict data you'r showing saved? Is this one of the `source`, `device` or `drain` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `defaultdict` from `collections` instead of checking if the key exists and then appending to it.

```
from collections import defaultdict
devices_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

To add to this dict:

```
device = Device_Terminals(line[0], line[1], line[3])
devices_dict[line[2]].append(device)
```

To search its values, you put a simple loop over the dictionary:

```
# your search term
search_val = 'device_name'
for key, devices in devices_dict.items():
    for device in devices:
        if search_val == device.device_name:
            print(key)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do dict lookup using its values. Try look at the solution of this previously answered question.

[Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: but what if the value is object and I need specific attribute to compare with? @boonwj

Comment: Since values in the dictionary is not unique, you will need to loop through all values in the dictionary and get the data you need.