# Get Dictionaries Key value inside an array

Tags: python, dictionary

Similar to this 
[Get Key by value question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary) but this time, the value is inside an array. The solution i think of is loop each item the Dictionary, and loop again for each items in the value pair. But from the looks of it, this is intensive. Is this the only way?

```
# a dictionary that contains ranges. this dictionary might have 1million keys and the range can have many values too
dictionary = {
            "x": range(0,10),
            "y": range(11,20),
            "z": range(21,30)
            .
            .
            .
        }
get_dictionary_value = 16
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    for item in v:
        if get_dictionary_value = item:
            print("the key is {}".format(k)) #the output will be "the key is y"
```

Comment: Why not just `for k, v in dictionary.items(): if get_dictionary_item in v: print(...)`? You can also `break` at that point if there'll only be one key. You could also consider alternative data structures (even just a reversed dictionary) if you do this a lot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, what do you think is the better approach in this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use-case for [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
dictionary = {
            "x": range(0,10),
            "y": range(11,20),
            "z": range(21,30)
        }

get_dictionary_value = 16

next(k for k,v in dictionary.items() if get_dictionary_value in v, 'No match')
```

Returns:

```
y
```

Comment: is this memory intensive? I know iterators is better than conventional loops

Comment: Not sure exactly in what perspective but this should with python3 be a loop over a generator. So quick answer: no.

Answer (score 1):

To stick with your approach you can use the *in*-statement as @Anton vBR mentioned. This checks if some item is included in a data structure (works not just on lists)

```
d = {
    "x": range(0,10),
    "y": range(11,20),
    "z": range(21,30)
}

query = 16
for k,v in d.items():
    if query in v: k

>>> 'y'
```

will return the key that matches your query

Comment: I have no issues running this, but im just wondering if this is memory intensive.