# How can I check If there is a specified value in a dict?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm setting up a script, and I need to know If there is a specified value in my dictionary.

```py
dict = {"1" : [1, 2, 3], "2" : [4, 5, 6]}
```

The fact is that I want to analyze all the lists from the dict values but I don't know how can I translate that.

How can I set a variable to `True` if `5` is in the dict?

Another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary) where you can find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Iterate over the dict : [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)
- Use `in` keyword

```py
for key, value in d.items():
    if 5 in value:
        print('5 in dict')
        break
```

- Use break to stop the loop after finding the value and to save time not iterating over the whole dict.

Use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` if you are using python2.

Comment: Really thanks, it works! If I want to return the key referring to this value, can I just return the key from the loop?

Comment: Yes, instead of `break` you can `return key`

Comment: For example, how can I return the index of the key instead of the key?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on my phone at 2:30am because I can't sleep, so bear with me for any bad formatting.

```
if any(5 in x for x in mydict.values()):
    print("dict analyzed")
```

That's one of the slick Pythonic ways of doing it. At a high level, you need to loop through `mydict.values()`, which provides an iterable of the values of `mydict` (`dict` is made up of key-value pairs.) If one of them contains 5, then print "dict analyzed."

The `any` function that I used is syntactic sugar; mind you, the high level idea remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, avoid assigning things to names of inbuilts like `dict`.

The following is specific to your use case:

```
mydict = {"1" : [1, 2, 3], "2" : [4, 5, 6]}
for key, vals in mydict.items():
    if 5 in vals:
        print('Dict analyzed')
```