# if item in dictionary == True -> return dictionary name as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need perform search in some dictionary structure :

```
dic_global = {
    'key_lev1_1': {
        'key_lev2_a': 'some_value_1',
        'key_lev2_b': 'some_value_2'
                  },
    'key_lev1_2': 'some_value_111'
}
```

and I need to perform recursive search for item in the whole structure so that function would return the key where the item was.
so if fun found 'key_lev2_a' it returns 'key_lev1_1' - the name of enclosure the key where the dict with 'key_lev2_a' is.

is it possible ?

Comment: What "dictionary name" are you talking about?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for your question with sample input and desired output

Comment: Dictionaries don't have names. Dictionary elements have keys, but `if item in dict` searches the keys, so `item` contains the key that was found.

Comment: To follow on from @Barmar, you can get the corresponding value with `dict[item]`. You can also skip the `if` using either `try` or else `dict.get(item)`. Finally, don't use `dict` as a variable name as you'll hide the built-in.

Comment: I think you might be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/8023306/5015356

Comment: I edited question for more clearness now

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_key(obj, key):
    if key in obj:
        return obj
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            item = find_key(v, key)
            if item is not None:
                return k
```

(source: modified [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary))

Comment: (this wont work if the key you are looking for is in the most parent dict because of obvious reason: this one does not have a parent key.)