# How to check a list for a specific item, while maintaining a kind of order?

Tags: python

I want to check if two items are in a list. But the method should follow a kind of order.

Here, I have a dictionary of people along with their favorite numbers. But the numbers are the keys and the people are the values.

```py
fav_num_dict = {13: 'A', 33: 'B', 23: 'C', 25: 'D', 11: 'E', 4: 'F'}

people_to_check = ["D", "B"]

for num, person in fav_num_dict.items():
    if person in people_to_check:
        print(fav_num_dict[num], num)
```

I am doing some kind of work where the order of the people in `people_to_check` matters. But when I run the script, it prints "B", with his/her number first and then "D". Now, that happens because "B" comes first in the dictionary and it also exists in `people_to_check` despite as the second item.

My question here is how do I make the program respect my order for `people_to_check`? Like, if it finds "B" first but it is the second item in my specified list, it should wait until it finds the first item, "D" and then "B".

I can also do a `people_to_check.reverse()` but that always won't work. Because `people_to_check` can also have items that are in order with the items in `fav_num_dict`

Comment: Your dictionary structure is error prone. Two people can have same favourite number. Invert your dictionary.

Comment: What if you iterate over the list people_to_check rather than fav_num_dict to maintain the correct order?

Comment: Just a point that there is no guarantee that a dictionary should maintain order.  You should be looping over the search terms if you want results in that order, not over the items in the dictionary.

Comment: @MrFelixU Python 3.7 preserves dict insertion order. So does CPython 3.6, but it's an implementation detail. See [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/4518341) But anyway it's beside the point cause like you said OP should be looping over the list, not the dict.

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed, but as you say that's not a language feature, it just so happens to be the case in the current implementation and I thought it was unwise to rely on that in one's algorithm.

Comment: @MrFelixU Your point stands, but it is a language feature in Python 3.7+. It's an implementation detail in CPython 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

you can invert your dictionary (if the names are unique...) then just use a regular dict lookup:

```py
fav_num_dict = {13: 'A', 33: 'B', 23: 'C', 25: 'D', 11: 'E', 4: 'F'}

reverse_dict = {v: k for k, v in fav_num_dict.items()}

people_to_check = ["D", "B"]

for person in people_to_check:
    if person in reverse_dict:
        print(person, reverse_dict[person])
```

Output:

```
D 25
B 33
```

Comment: I appreciate your opinion to invert the dictionary but there can be scenarios where my structure might be preferred. An example is a dictionary where the keys are "Person 1", "Person 2", etc.. and the values are their names? And I have to check if a person exists in that dict? I need to iterate over dict.items() since I need both the key and value. Thanks to the above comments, I iterated over my list and then I iterated over dict.items() and then checked if the person is the value of any item in the dict. My apologies for not using an idea dictionary as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the desired order by iterating over the list `people_to_check` and querying the reversed_dictionary if the person is present in it. For example, you can do something like-

```
fav_num_dict = {13: 'A', 33: 'B', 23: 'C', 25: 'D', 11: 'E', 4: 'F'}
reversed_dict = dict((val,key) for key, val in fav_num_dict.items())

people_to_check = ["D", "B"]

for person in people_to_check:
    if person in reversed_dict:
        print(person, reversed_dict[person])
```

This will work only if each number is uniquely associated to a person, if a person who likes more than two numbers and is one of the people_to_check, you might get one of the numbers that he likes and not all.

Comment: `dict()` can take a generator, so the list is not needed: `dict((val, key) for key, val in fav_num_dict.items())`. It's even simpler to do a dict comprehension like in Adam's answer: `{v: k for k, v in fav_num_dict.items()}`

Comment: @ wjandrea: Thanks for the the suggestion. Modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way that you iterate on `people_to_check` and then find the key associated with the value present in `people_to_check` by using dict.keys() and dict.values().

```
fav_num_dict = {13: 'A', 33: 'B', 23: 'C', 25: 'D', 11: 'E', 4: 'F'}
people_to_check = ["D", "B", "E"]
for person in people_to_check:
    if person in fav_num_dict.values():
        k = 0
        while fav_num_dict[list(fav_num_dict.keys())[k]] != person:
            k = k+1
        print(person, list(fav_num_dict.keys())[k])
```

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also make a function and you'll get key of any value inside a dict by using function by passing dict and a value for which you have to find key to it. go through this link [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary/14624923)