# Retrieve keys using values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically I am trying to find a way to get the key  of a value from a dictionary by searching the value.

```
people = {
    "Sarah" : "36",
    "David" : "42",
    "Ricky" : "13"
    }


user_input = ('Enter the age of the individual") #The user enters the 
                                                 #value 
key_to_output = (...) #The variable that would contain the key value
print(key_to_output)
```

For example in the dictionary above if the user enters "36", they would be returned have "Sarah" returned. The dictionary I am using will never have a overlapping values so don't worry about any issues that would cause.

Also, because my python knowledge isn't very advanced it would be much appreciated if the responses were kept quite amateur so I can understand them properly.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary

Comment: What if the dict is `people = {
    "Sarah" : "36",
    "David" : "36",
    "Ricky" : "13"
    }` What answer do you want if you search for `36`? `["Sarah", "David"]`?  Either one?
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: I would ignore the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi, I just thought of that and was updating. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert the dictionary as so -

```
people_inv = {v:k for k,v in people.items()}
```

Now say your user inputted 36,

```
user_input = "36"
people_inv[user_input] # this will give Sarah
```

If the values are not unique like in the example below, you can do this -

```
people = {"Sarah":36, "Ricky":36, "Pankaj":28} 
people_inv= {}
for k,v in people.items():
    people_inv.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
people_inv["36"]
```

Output

```
['Sarah', 'Ricky']
```

Comment: How would I go about turning the line people_inv['36'] into  people_inv[x] where x = the user_input? I tried print(people[user_input]) but got a key error when i entered 36.

Comment: @Richard302 `x = int(user_input)`

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way would be to itterate over the values like this.

```py
    def find_key(value, people):
        for name in people:
            if people[name] == value:
                return name
```

If you are trying to get mutliple keys I would try:

```py
   def find_key(value, people):
       names = []
       for name in people:
           if people[name] == value:
               names.append(name)
       return names
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I shall also try this format out!