# Getting key based on values in list of a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to get the Key based on values in a list of the key or return the element if the value/key is not found in the dict.

```
headersDict = {'Number; SEX AND AGE - Total Population':['TPop'],
               'Number; SEX AND AGE - Male Population':['MPop'],
               'Number; SEX AND AGE - Female Population':['FPop'],
               'Under 5 years': ['<5'],
               '5 to 9 years': ['5_9'],
               '10 to 14 years': ['10_14'],
               '15 to 19 years': ['15_19'],
               '20 to 24 years': ['20_24'],
               '25 to 29 years': ['25_29'],
               '30 to 34 years': ['30_34'],
               '35 to 39 years': ['35_39'],
               '40 to 44 years': ['40_44'],
               '45 to 49 years': ['45_49'],
               '50 to 54 years': ['50_54'],
               '55 to 59 years': ['55_59'],
               '60 to 64 years': ['60_64'],
               '65 to 69 years': ['65_69'],
               '70 to 74 years': ['70_74'],
               '75 to 79 years': ['75_79'],
               '80 to 84 years': ['80_84'],
               '85 years and over': ['85+'],
               'Median age(years)': ['Medage'],
               '16 years and over': ['16+'],
               '18 years and over': ['18+'],
               '21 years and over': ['21+'],
               '62 years and over': ['62+', 'sixty two+'],
               '65 years and over': ['65+', 'sixty five+']}

headersList = [  '1+', '25_29', '85+',
                '65+'
                ]
new_headersList = [k for k, v in headersDict.items() for elem in headersList for val in v if elem == val]


print(new_headersList)
```

If I try the above, I get the output as:

```
$ python 1.py 
['25 to 29 years', '85 years and over', '65 years and over']
```

What I require is:

```
$ python 1.py 
['1+', '25 to 29 years', '85 years and over', '65 years and over']
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: 1+ isn't in your headers dict, right?  Also, consider breaking your list comprehension into For loops, it will make it easier to understand and troubleshoot for that complicated of a comprehension.

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of lists with a single item? This seems like the unfortunate result of poor design.

Comment: maybe write list comprehension as normal loop and then you will better see how it works and it will be easier to modify it.

Comment: Your code is going over the dict and printing all keys where the values contain one of the expected headers. But there is no `1+` anywhere in the dict. Is your input data wrong or the business logic?

Comment: i think thats why `1+` is still `1+` in his expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Comment: JoranBeasley is right. I think I did not articulate it right. If the key is not found, then i just want the not found result back, so that I dont miss on it.
AlexanderCécile: I have lists in the value, since I can have a bunch of sources, that will be in different ways to denote or represent, and i'm trying to unify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these problems are typically easier if you invert your dict

```
inverted_dict = {val:key for key,arr in my_dict.items() for val in arr}
```

now you can simply lookup your keys

```
for key in [  '1+', '25_29', '85+', '65+']:
    print(inverted_dict.get(key,key))
```

Comment: The idea is good, but you might want to make it more applicable to the data structures and variable names of the question.

Comment: i would rather make it more broadly applicable to assist others with similar questions in the future ... anyone on here should be able to draw the correct connections

Answer (score 1):

This code inverses the dictionary so that each value within the array becomes a new key. With that inversed dictionary it's very easy to query individual header keys or fall back to the header name.

```py
headersDict = {'Number; SEX AND AGE - Total Population': ['TPop'],
               'Number; SEX AND AGE - Male Population': ['MPop'],
               'Number; SEX AND AGE - Female Population': ['FPop'],
               'Under 5 years': ['<5'],
               '5 to 9 years': ['5_9'],
               '10 to 14 years': ['10_14'],
               '15 to 19 years': ['15_19'],
               '20 to 24 years': ['20_24'],
               '25 to 29 years': ['25_29'],
               '30 to 34 years': ['30_34'],
               '35 to 39 years': ['35_39'],
               '40 to 44 years': ['40_44'],
               '45 to 49 years': ['45_49'],
               '50 to 54 years': ['50_54'],
               '55 to 59 years': ['55_59'],
               '60 to 64 years': ['60_64'],
               '65 to 69 years': ['65_69'],
               '70 to 74 years': ['70_74'],
               '75 to 79 years': ['75_79'],
               '80 to 84 years': ['80_84'],
               '85 years and over': ['85+'],
               'Median age(years)': ['Medage'],
               '16 years and over': ['16+'],
               '18 years and over': ['18+'],
               '21 years and over': ['21+'],
               '62 years and over': ['62+', 'sixty two+'],
               '65 years and over': ['65+', 'sixty five+']}


headersDictReversed = {}
for k, v in headersDict.items():
  for new_k in v:
    headersDictReversed[new_k] = k

headersList = ['1+', '25_29', '85+', '65+']
results = []
for header in headersList:
  # Return the value for header and default to the header itself.
  results.append(headersDictReversed.get(header, header))
print(results)
```

> ['1+', '25 to 29 years', '85 years and over', '65 years and over']

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pandas, you can use this solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(headersDict, index=[0,1]).T.reset_index()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1[0], df1[1]]).drop_duplicates()).join(df1, lsuffix='_1').drop(columns=['0',1]).rename(columns={'0_1':0}) 
a = pd.DataFrame(headersList).merge(df1, 'outer')[0:len(pd.DataFrame(headersList))].set_index(0)['index'] 
a.fillna(a.index.to_series()).values.tolist() 


# ['1+', '25 to 29 years', '85 years and over', '65 years and over']
```