# Python how to match two dictionaries' values in nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I stumbled over another problem that I just can't seem to get.

I have this dictionary 
`fruit_count = {'apple': 5, 'banana': 7, 'orange': 4, 'melon': 9}` and

and a nested dictionary

```
students_fruit_count = { 'Brandon':  {'apple': 2, 'banana': 7, 'orange': 3, 'melon': 8},
'Joan':  {'apple': 11, 'banana': 8, 'orange': 3, 'melon': 6}, 
'Tanya':  {'apple': 5, 'banana': 7, 'orange': 4, 'melon': 9}}
```

Now I am trying to build a code that prints out the name of the student that has the exact same fruit counts as the fruit_count dictionary values.

So in the problem above, the code should print out `Tanya`.

Here's my code (which obviously doesn't work):

```
for key in fruit_dict:
    for key2 in students_fruit_count:
        if key[i] == key2[j]:
            print('key2')
```

Any advice or explanation to such problem? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in students_fruit_count:
    if students_fruit_count[i] == fruit_count:
        print(i)
```

Or for a more Pythonic approach

```
result = [i for i in students_fruit_count if students_fruit_count[i]==fruit_count]
```

This will return a list containing all student names.