# How to get a value out of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = dict()
uid1 = 1
uid2 = 2
a[uid1] = {}
a[uid2] = {}
iid1 = 45
iid2 = 98
iid3 = 3
iid4 = 82
iid5 = 11
a[uid1][iid1] = 125
a[uid2][iid2] = 7
a[uid1][iid3] = 4
a[uid2][iid4] = 10
a[uid2][iid5] = 20
```

get a:

```
{1: {45: 125, 3: 4}, 2: {98: 7, 82: 10, 11: 20}}
```

What I want to get is to calculate the sum of 125+4=129 and 7+10+20=37

I've tried this:

```
for u,items in a.items():
    for i,counts in items.items():
        for count in counts:
            print(count)
```

got a notice like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-8b6a2dace81e> in <module>
      1 for u,items in a.items():
      2     for i,counts in items.items():
----> 3         for count in counts:
      4             print(count)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: By the time you're at the second for loop, `counts` is already the numbers you want (125, 4, etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get key by value in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023306/get-key-by-value-in-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close

```
for u,items in a.items():
    print(sum(items.values()))

129
37
```

**Explanation**

Your error occurs on your counts.values() call. For each iteration of your first loop, items is a dictionary.

```
for u, items in a.items():
    print(items)

{45: 125, 3: 4}
{98: 7, 82: 10, 11: 20}
```

You can see what counts is with your next loop

```
for u,items in a.items():
    for i, count in items.items():
        print(count)

125
4
7
10
20
```

count is an integer. If you wanted to keep your two loop structure, you could do

```
for u,items in a.items():
    sum = 0
    for i, count in items.items():
        sum += count
    print(sum)

129
37
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, try with single line.

```
a = {1: {45: 125, 3: 4}, 2: {98: 7, 82: 10, 11: 20}}
print([sum(values.values()) for key,values in a.items()])
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can calculate your result:

```
result = [sum(dct.values()) for dct in a.values()]
print(result) # [129, 37]
```

Problem in your code is next:

```
for u,items in a.items():
    for i,counts in items.items():
        print(counts) # it prints 125, 4, 7, 10, 20
```

In your code you trying to iterate `counts` which is `int` number