# How to remove a value from Map(Type, List)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of items (`excluded_names`) and a dict (`date_dict`), I am trying to remove the value from the list of values in the `date_dict`.

```
def _get_dates(name):
    DATE_FORMATS = ['%Y%m%d', '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S']
    for date_format in DATE_FORMATS:
        try:
            date_of_index = datetime.strptime(name.split('-')[-1], date_format).date()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    else:
        date_of_index = date.today()
    return date_of_index

date_dict = defaultdict(list)
index_list = ['test', 
'name-20180213', 
'name-20180102_000012', 
'name-20180102', 
'name-20180101_000012', 
'name-20180101_000016'] 
for name in index_list:
   date_dict[_get_dates(name)].append(name)

>>> date_dict
    defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): ['name-20180102_000012', 'name-20180102'], datetime.date(2020, 2, 4): ['testname'], datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): ['name-20180101_000012', 'name-20180101_000016'], datetime.date(2018, 2, 13): ['name-20180213']})
>>> excluded_names = ['name-20180102_000012']
```

I need to remove the value from `defaultdict`. I tried:

```
if excluded_names in _get_list_to_delete_from(date_dict, 2):
    for values in date_dict.values():
                for v in values:
                    if v in excluded_names:
                        values.remove(v)
import itertools
def _get_list_to_delete_from(date_dict, index_to_keep):
    keys_to_delete = sorted(date_dict(), reverse=True)[index_to_keep:] #I need to keep the dates
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([date_dict[key] for key in keys_to_delete]))
```

But it's not deleting that particular value. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: `defaultdict` (and its base class, `dict`) does not have a `remove` method.

Comment: why are you doing `sorted(date_dict()...)`? You can't call a `dict` instance

Comment: a `default_dict` is not really different from a `dict` as far as removing items goes, so this question appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Grismar: The OP actually asked how to _remove_ something from the dictionary. Using a dictionary comprehension or generator expression, as shown in the accepted answer to the duplicate question, will result in a regular dictionary (i.e. it will no longer be a `defaultdict`) — which may or may not matter to the OP. This can be fixed, of course, but I feel should be pointed out.

Comment: @martineau - that's why the second answer in that link has some deserved upvotes, it shows how to go about it using `del`

Comment: @Grismar: Good point…obviously I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove from the dictionary itself, not the list inside the dictionary. Try this:

```
for single_date in date_dict:
    for name in date_dict[single_date]:
        if name in excluded_names:
            date_dict[single_date].remove(name)
```

Comment: Still not deleting.

Comment: Just a confirmation, but do you want to remove the string element from the list or the list from the dictionary? My code is for the first case.

Comment: >>> if excluded_index_name in _get_list_to_delete_from(date_dict, 2):
...     for single_date in date_dict:
...        for name in date_dict[single_date]:
...            if name in excluded_index_name:
...               date_dict[single_date].remove(name)
>>> date_dict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): ['name-1-20180102_000012', 'name-1-20180102'], datetime.date(2020, 2, 4): ['testname'], datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): ['name-1-20180101_000012', 'name-1-20180101_000016'], datetime.date(2018, 2, 13): ['name-1-20180213']})

Comment: If you want to remove the list from the dict, substitute the last line for (del date_dict[single_date])

Comment: I need to remove the string from the list..tried yours but still not deleting

Answer (score 0):

There are a few difficulties in using a dictionary for this, namely that you're trying to delete keys by looking up values ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8023337)) and that to remove items from a dictionary (by using del) with an iterative approach results in “RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration”.

I tried firstly searching for the keys to delete, appending them to a list, and then deleting them from the dictionary like below:

```
delete_keys = []

for key, val in d.items():
    for i in val:
        if i in excluded_names:
            delete_keys.append(key)

for i in delete_keys:
    del d[i]
```

Comment: I just want to delete 1 item from that values not the entire key.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row_values in defaultdict.values():
    for value in row_values: 
        if(value in excluded_names):
            row_values.remove(value)
```

[My Code EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8guPD.png)

Comment: It seems like working for you but mine its not. Is there anything wrong with my dict ? It says defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): ['name-20180102_000012', 'name-20180102'], datetime.date(2020, 2, 4): ['testname'], datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): ['name-20180101_000012', 'name-20180101_000016'], datetime.date(2018, 2, 13): ['name-20180213']})

Comment: replace " (<type 'list'>, " with " = " 
and remove last " ) " 


it will be somthing like this 

defaultdict =  {datetime.date(2018, 1, 2): ['name-20180102_000012', 'name-20180102'],
                            datetime.date(2020, 2, 4): ['testname'],
                            datetime.date(2018, 1, 1): ['name-20180101_000012', 'name-20180101_000016'],
                            datetime.date(2018, 2, 13): ['name-20180213']}

Comment: I used defaultdict(list) to create the map. Updated the question with full code.